# Footnote to a footnote

Tags: footnotes, nesting

How can I make a footnote to a footnote? E.g.,

```
Playfair's axiom\footnote{so called in honor of mathematician John Playfair, etc, etc., but was actually discovered by Proclus\footnote{Greek mathematician, etc, etc.}}
```

Comment: Personal opinion: don't do this.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do it for a formal and serious article, but it is not the case, and I think it's fun.

Comment: Some manual `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` trickery should do it, but like @Seamus I would do it.

Comment: Go ahead and do it and have fun. See "House of Leaves" for wonderfully nested footnotes and crazy text layout, and also a good story.

Comment: The package `bigfoot` does this (example given in the manual).  It is not a normal need, but critical editions which themselves include a scholarly apparatus may make such a situation necessary.

Comment: Terry Pratchett used a lot of footnotes within footnotes in his books and I absolutely love it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Playfair's axiom\footnote{%
so called in honor of mathematician John Playfair, etc, etc.,
but was actually discovered by Proclus\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{Greek mathematician, etc, etc.}
```

But I'd advise against doing this.

As a bonus, here's an example of how you can really mess with footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\footnotetext[4]{We have to go back to the future, Marty!}
Foo\footnote{The footnote to this sentence is true\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{The footnote to this sentence is false\footnotemark[1]} 
more body text\footnotetext[42]{This footnote doesn't appear in the main text}
And more body text\footnote{And we're back to the normal numbering.}
But look where this footnote text ends up!\footnotemark
\end{document}
```

A few points.

- The footnotes appear in the order the `\footnotemark`s appear in the text.
- Optional arguments to both `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` give you control over what number actually appears. (Useful for repeating a footnote if it is relevant again later.
- Everything here should work perfectly with `\label` and `\ref`

Body text:

[image: body text]

Footnotes:

[image: footnotes]

Comment: The same trick allows you do get footnotes in minipages. And there it is more useful...

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about these footnotemark and footnotetext commands. Thank you. I promise not to overuse it ;)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of footnotes in general. If it's important enough to mention, it's important enough for the main text. Rule of thumb: never have more footnotes than pages. But that's just me...

Comment: Here is more information on [`\footnotemark[<num>]`](http://www.uz.ac.zw/science/maths/latex/ltx-232.html) and [`\footnotetext[<num>]{<text>}`](http://www.uz.ac.zw/science/maths/latex/ltx-234.html), since it actually allows overriding of the mark used in the footnote.

Comment: @Werner thanks for that! I'll update my answer into a proper "here's how footnotes work" answer tomorrow. (it's 1am here)

Answer (score 14):

Use the `bigfoot` package (as I suggested in the above comment).  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{Default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{B}% perhaps also useful to know about

\begin{document}

\verb+bigfoot+%
\footnote{Available on CTAN.} %
improves \LaTeX's%
\footnoteB{Widely known to be less than ideal.} %
footnoting abilities.  \verb+bigfoot+%
\footnote{Available on CTAN.} %
improves \LaTeX's%
\footnoteB{Widely known to be less than ideal.\footnote{See also over
here: one important limitation is that ``Higher-placed footnotes
can't be anchored in inferior ones'' (see \verb+bigfoot.sty+).}} % 
footnoting abilities.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this code but I just keep getting "Package bigfoot Error \fooinsdefault forbidden in \fooinsdefault' any ideas?