# Chapter name in the header with \chapter*

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I need to display the chapter name with the `\chapter*` command to the left side of the header. This is one example of what I tried:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{\fancyplain{}{\textit{\leftmark}}}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{\centerline{Chapter Name}}

    \end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try

```
\chapter*{chapter name}
\markboth{chapter name}{}
```

And consider using `titlesec` package rather using `\centerline` as a visual formatting approach.

Comment: Ok, using this command in the header appears "Chapter0. Chapter Name". I would like having only the chapter name, without "Chapter0".

Comment: @FordPrefect sorry. comes from not thinking ... nice to get 3 votes for a wrong solution. People give too much credit :-)

Answer (score 11):

Setting the headers with `fancyhdr` usually requires changing the `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` commands; you don't need the latter, as you want only the chapter title in the header.

Here's an example in which I show two methods. A simple `\chapter` command in the `\frontmatter` will not give a numbering and correctly set the header. If you want the unnumbered chapter in the `\mainmatter`, then you can use an explicit `\chaptermark` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Another introduction}
\chaptermark{Another introduction}

\kant

\chapter{Title}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Note that if you plan to use appendices, one of the commands should be modified:

```
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\makeatother
```

(Unfortunately, the command that holds either `\chaptername` or `\appendixname` is an internal one, so one has to do some tricks to access it.)

Note also the `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}` to give the header the room it needs.

For centering the chapter title it's better to use the methods of the `titlesec` or `sectsty` packages than doing explicit formatting.

***Note*** This assumes that the unnumbered chapter is in the `\frontmatter` (any number of them, actually) or there is *only one* at the beginning of the `\mainmatter`. For other cases a more complex approach should be taken.

Comment: Can I add /footnotes{text} to this in the fancyhead section? Unsure how.

Comment: I think I found a solution. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74992/137109

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually using this function I wrote:

```tex
\newcommand{\silentchapter}[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}
```

It creates a chapter without a number and sets the header. The commented line adds this chapter to the contents index.