# Aconym Styles in Book

Tags: acronyms, acro

I am trying to create a list of acronyms. I am facing two problems. First, I want that text should appear like this, where full form of acronym in lower case, like this.

"A number of problems were faced by financial institutions (FIs) during the global financial crisis (GFC)."

However, the first letter of each word is in upper case. Moreover, I want that in the list of acronyms first letter of each word should be in upper case. So changing the long form in declaring acronym does not solve the problem.

Second, list of acronym does not appear like other list e.g. list of tables or list of figures. It appeared on the same page where list of figure was. I used \clearpage command but on the header list of figure still appears and the style of the heading is also not similar to other headings e.g. list of figures or list of tables.

The minimal working example is given below:

```
       \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
       \usepackage{authblk}
       \usepackage{titlesec}
       \usepackage{acro}
       %%%% Acroynym Entries %%%%
       \DeclareAcronym{gfc}{short =GFC, long = Global Financial Crisis}
       \DeclareAcronym{fi}{short =FI, long = Financial Institution, short-plural-form = FIs, long-plural-form = Financial Institutions}

       \begin{document}
       \author{Ahmed Arif}
       \title{Book Title}
       \date{November 2016}

       \frontmatter
       \maketitle
       \tableofcontents
       \listoftables
       \listoffigures
       \clearpage
       \printacronyms[name= List of Acronyms,sort=true]

       \mainmatter

       \chapter{Introduction}

       \section{Background of the Study}
       A number of problems were faced by \acp{fi} during the \ac{gfc}. 

       \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The long version of the acronyms are printed exactly as the entry given to `long=`, to get lower cases in the text for the long version, write the long value in lower case i.e. `long = global financial crisis`.  To have the entry in the list differ from the `long` version of the acronym you can use the `list` key to pass what should go in the acronym list.
[`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) defines `\Ac` and similar variants which print with the first letter capitalised which may be useful to know.

The acronyms list is (by default) printed as a `section*` to get it to appear like other lists I imagine what you want is to have the acronyms printed under a `chapter*` environment instead, this can be done by passing the `heading` key to `\printacronyms` with `heading=chapter*` (having done this you can now remove the `\clearpage`.

Thus my guess at the desired output would be the result of

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{acro}
%%%% Acroynym Entries %%%%
\DeclareAcronym{gfc}{short =GFC, long = global financial crisis, list = Global Financial Crisis}
\DeclareAcronym{fi}{short =FI, long = financial institution, short-plural-form = FIs, long-plural-form = Financial Institutions, list = Financial Institution}

\begin{document}
\author{Ahmed Arif}
\title{Book Title}
\date{November 2016}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printacronyms[name= List of Acronyms,sort=true,heading=chapter*]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Background of the Study}
A number of problems were faced by \acp{fi} during the \ac{gfc}. 
\end{document}
```

Producing the following output for the list of acronyms
[image]
and main text
[image]

Comment: Thank you @DaiBowen. Still one problem. A page before and page after acronym still shows list of figures in the header. And these pages are otherwise blank.

Comment: @AhmedArif If you don't mind `List of Acronyms` appearing in your ToC you can just use `heading=chapter`.  Or to keep `List of Acronyms` out of your ToC you can use `\markboth{List of Acronyms}{}` just after `\printacronyms` as per [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89915/106162).