# How to improve this tex problems (lhead,rhead)

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\lipsum
\chapter{one}

\chapter{two}

\chapter{three}

\chapter{four}
\end{document}
```

i want to obtain automatically Introduction instead of contents

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The issue you observe is cause by "Introduction" being an unnumbered chapter. You can solve this by using `\markboth` as also explained here: [Chapter name in the header with \chapter*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89914/134144)

Comment: Unnumbered introduction should not be in the toc? Seems reasonable list also, and then there are another easy solution for this case.

Comment: thank you @leandriis