# How to put footnote in footer

Tags: footnotes, footer

I'm using memoir and by default, footnote appears above footer:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\begin{document}

paragraph\footnote{a footnote}\footnote{another footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to put footnote in footer like this image:

[image]

I've found only one similar workaround here: [footnote in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/footnote-in-footer)

However, this method does not allow multiple footnote in one page. Even though I have only one or two footnotes in a page, still multiple footnote would be used.

I've also read another workaround which just hides footrule and use footnoterule as footrule but in that case, the body text height would be changed depending on footnote.

The ultimate purpose to put footnote in footer is not to change body content height even if footnotes exist.

I don't care page number could be overwritten by footnote because I'll put page number in header.

How can I make such footnote?

Comment: this question cannot be answered without knowing at least the document class you are using, and any relevant packages.  what you describe that you want is the default behavior of most document classes.  so an mwe is really needed to see what is happening in your case.  (mwe = as small as possible compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem you are having)

Comment: @barbarabeeton sorry for missing information. I edited the question. I'm using memoir class.

Comment: i'm not familiar enough with `memoir` to suggest an intelligent answer.  but i do have a question ... what do you wish to happen if you have either many footnotes, or just one or two really long ones?  they would "be told" to continue down off the bottom of the page, and i don't think that's what you would want.

Comment: I suppose one could define a new area sort of like marginpar only below the text area.  Whether you call it the footer or something else is semantics.  Currently only the bottom of the footer is defined (\footskip below the text area).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do not write such long footnote or many footnotes in one page, so it's totally ok even if too many footnotes overflow the page.

Comment: @xylosper -- *you* may not accumulate a large crop of footnotes on one page, but this forum is read by other users who might be looking for a similar answer without such restraint.  that's why i wanted to put this condition "on the record".

Comment: The flowfram package can be used to add a dynamic frame below the text area in which to place footones.  One would have to replace the current code to print \footins (see source2 from CTAN).