# Putting footnote below footer

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr

[image]

Hello, using `\footnote{insert footnote}`looks weird with my footer defined as follows. Is there a method to put the footnote below the footer line? Or any other presentation that looks good

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
```

I also landed on [footnote-in-footer‌​](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/footnote-in-footer]), and it seems like what I exactly want, but somehow doesn't work for me.[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/footnote-in-footer‌​]

Comment: I've never seen footnotes below the footer line.

Comment: @egreg wrong question then, i am sorry. however, is there a way to make it look better?

Comment: Yes: remove the footer line. Or put footnotes in the outer margin, if it's wide  enough, and you don't have too many footnotes per page.

Comment: a similar question is [How to put footnote in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388581/579); this hasn't been answered, but there is a suggestion in the last comment that might be helpful.  (not tested or acknowledged.)

Answer (score 2):

add this in your preamble
`\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions (not mutually exclusive):

- Don't use a footer line.
- Load the `footmisc` package with the option `bottom`. This will ensure that the footnote(s) will always be placed at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Noted! I also landed on this, and it seems like what I exactly want, but somehow doesn't work for me.[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/footnote-in-footer]

Comment: @KushaVerma - The "solution" in the link you provide "works" if, and only if, there's only one footnote per page that doesn't occupy more than two lines. Not a very general solution, in my view...