# Inserting footnote under the footrule in fancyhdr

Tags: footnotes, fancyhdr

I want my footnotes to appear under the footer. My MWE

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \lhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
 \rhead{\thepage}
 \fancyheadoffset{0\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
 \nouppercaseheads
 \usepackage{times}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
 \chapterstyle{bianchi}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{example}
 \Blindtext \footnote{I want this under the fancy footer}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23486/15925 help?

Comment: Is the question an duplicat to the question(linked by Andrew)?