# footnote in footer overflows on two pages

Tags: footnotes, footer, overflow

I want to have the footnotes in the footer and I implemented [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/footnote-in-footer) from Aram Becker.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[bmargin=1.4cm,tmargin=1.5cm,hmargin=2cm,headsep=0.3cm,footnotesep=0cm,footskip=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\let\origfootrule\footrule
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\iffootnote{}{\origfootrule}}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\origfootrule}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-15]
test \footnote{\lipsum[1-8]}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the footnote overflows on the next page but stop overflowing after (if you change the length of the lipsum in the footnote), so it is like it's capped only for the footnote's page.

Comment: you mean the footnote is split over two pages? That is quite normal, and you would get a very bad page with lots of white space if you tried to prevent that. If you don't like it, don't put so much text into the footnotes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To do this in the MWE it needs a dozen of lines, so the "If you don't like it, don't put so much text into the footnotes" would be a fine solution but in my main document it only needs couples of lines. If I write an equation in the footnote it will mess up like this.

Comment: well you can use `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`. If your footnote contains paragraphs you will have to suppress breaks there too. And personnally I wouldn't put an equation in the footnote. My footnotes are rarely longer than one or two lines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I already tried and surprisingly it doesn't work.

Comment: as I said: there can be other breakpoints like paragraph breaks. In your example use e.g. `\lipsum*[1-8]` to see the difference.

Comment: If you use the [showframe] options of geometry, you will see that the footer is still below the text area and the footnote is in the text area.  All you did is make the margins smaller.