# Footception: Footnote within a footnote within a footnote

Tags: footnotes, nesting, bigfoot

Inspired by the question [Footnote to a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/footnote-to-a-footnote) (where it was asked if one could have a footnote reference in a footnote), I'm asking something a bit more complex. Before I ask though, let me prefence the question by stating that *I'm not looking for the standard tyopgraphical practice*, but rather asking if something is possible for my own sake. How can I put a footnote section within another footnote section, i.e.

```
This is the outer block of[1] text[2].

---- % Begin first footnote (scriptsize)
[1] Here we start the first[*] footnote to main.
[2] Here we start the second footnote to main.

 ---- % Begin second footnote (even smaller then scriptsize)
 [*] Here is the first[+] footnote[-] to the first footnote block.

   ---- % Begin third footnote (even smaller then the last one)
   [+] Here is the first[a] footnote to the second[b] footnote block.
   [-] Here is the second footnote to the second[c] footnote block.
```

etc ... I'm looking for footnotes all the way down, or at least as deep as I'd like to specify.

Comment: Epic title. Good thing you (foot)noted you're not after typographic practice... See what I did there? `;)`

Comment: @Werner Typographic practice varies.  For critical editions multilevel footnotes are a must.  Imagine a modern edition of a Greek text translated by a medieval scholar.  You have the notes of the original translator, *and* the notes of the modern editor, which may reference both the original text and the translator's notes. AFAIK, David Kastrup's package was developed for a critical edition of this kind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The packages `bigfoot` and `manyfoot` have this functionality.  See this example from the [`bigfoot` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/bigfoot.pdf):

[image]

Unfortunately, the customization of footnotes in `bigfoot` is not well documented (David calls this "expert options" and suggests reading the code).  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\makeatletter
\let\@makefntext@orig\@makefntext
\FootnoteSpecific{B}\def\@makefntext{\@makefntext@orig\tiny}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Text\footnoteA{Footnote\footnoteB{Another footnote}}.  More
text\footnoteA{This footnote goes to the first level}\footnoteB{And
  this to the second one}.  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for, in the Bigfoot example you gave there is only one _visible_ footnote section that references itself, albeit with two internal footnote sections. What I'd like is a _second_ footnote section that references the first footnote section with a smaller typeface then the last and another line separating the two, as if the first footnote section was an independent part of the text.

Comment: Looking deeper, maybe it _is_ possible, but it doesn't seem like there is a visual demarcation between the footnotes, maybe a MWE would help?

Comment: You can add rules between the levels and change appearance of each footnote level.  See the documentation of `manyfoot` (`bigfoot` inherits it).  Look at the commands `\SetFootnoteHook` and `\SelectFootnoteRule`.

Comment: I looked into the documentaiton of `bigfoot` and understood that changing the font of footnotes, while possible, is *not* documented (the author suggests reading the code).  I added an example showing how to do this - hope it helps.

Comment: I know this has been a few years, but how can I increase the font size of footnoteB ?

Comment: Change `\tiny` in `\FootnoteSpecific{B}\def\@makefntext{\@makefntext@orig\tiny}`to something like `\small`