# Nested footnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes

The footception post ([Footception: Footnote within a footnote within a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35223/footception-footnote-within-a-footnote-within-a-footnote)) describes how to recursively footnote. I am trying to make a nested footnote that is placed in the same footnote apparatus as the calling footnote, but the numbering goes awry. Here is a MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    This is a footnote\footnote{Here is a footnote within the footnote\footnotemark{}. And here is another one\footnotemark{}.}
    \footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled `2'}
    \footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled `3'}
    \end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: footnotemark_fail]

Note the errant footnote numbering. How can this be rectified? I would like to use automatic footnote enumeration, therefore temporary solutions like `\footnotemark[2]{}` and `\footnotetext[2]{}` should be avoided.

**Major Edit #1:**
The package `bigfoot` was suggested by **jon** as offering a solution to this problem; however, while `bigfoot` permits construction of multiple footnote apparatus and allows commenting from a superior apparatus to an inferior one, the below MWE shows that `bigfoot` fails to permit intra-apparatus footnoting (as well as footnoting from an inferior to a superior apparatus):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{bigfoot}
    \DeclareNewFootnote{default}
    \DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
    \MakeSortedPerPage{B}
    \begin{document}
    This text has a footnote in the default apparatus%
    \footnote{Here.}%
    as well as an alphabetical apparatus%
    \footnoteB{Here.}.
    \verb+bigfoot+ allows subordinate footnotes from a superior apparatus to an inferior apparatus%
    \footnote{Like this\footnoteB{See.}.}, but not from an inferior apparatus to a superior apparatus%
    \footnoteB{Like this\footnote{Error.}.}. %
    Likewise, \verb+bigfoot+ forbids making a nested footnote from one apparatus to the same apparatus%
    \footnote{Like this\footnote{Error}.}\footnoteB{And like this\footnoteB{Error}.}. %
    A quick look at \verb+bigfoot.sty+ shows this to be true: \textit{``Higher-placed footnotes can't be anchored %
    in inferior ones.''} This means one cannot call a footnote from an inferior to superior apparatus or even from %
    one apparatus to the same apparatus. I am particularly interested in footnoting from one apparatus to the same %
    apparatus. I do not want multiple apparatus \footnote{Yes this is the correct plural\footnote{Fail.}.}.
    \end{document}
```

For convenience, I have posted the output as a .tif image:
[image: bigfoot_fail]

Comment: `bigfoot` allows for nested footnotes.

Comment: Actually, this is not a duplicate. The footception post describes how to make subordinate footnotes. I am trying to make a nested footnote that is placed in the same footnote apparatus as the calling footnote.

Comment: Sorry for closing your question prematurely. I voted for reopening.

Comment: Thank you very much @lockstep. I will post a more detailed latex input file and output to explain further.

Comment: I'll admit I upvoted this for two reasons: 1) having multiple clear MWE (Though it looks like that was added after based on the comments, but anyway, it is good now) and 2) Using the term footception.

Comment: Another possible solution can be found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38898/6865 (including support for hyperref).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be possible to redefine the way `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` operate. Here is one such a possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\newcounter{fnmarkcntr}\newcounter{fntextcntr}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnotemark}{% Taken from article.cls
   \@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{fnmarkcntr}% added 
      \refstepcounter{footnote}\label{footnotemark\thefnmarkcntr}% modified
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
      \@footnotemark}}
\makeatother
\LetLtxMacro{\oldfootnotetext}{\footnotetext}% store \footnotetext in \oldfootnotetext
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{fntextcntr}% step to next "footnotemark"
  \oldfootnotetext[\ref{footnotemark\thefntextcntr}]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a footnote\footnote{Here is a footnote within the footnote\footnotemark. And here is another one\footnotemark.}
\footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled '2'.}
\footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled '3'.}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to redefine `\footnotemark` to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` and apply a label for each use of `\footnotemark` via some counter (`fnmarkcntr` in the above case). Then, for every successive use of `\footnotetext{<text>}` the appropriate label is pulled an placed in the optional argument `\oldfootnotetex[..]{<text>}`. This requires two compiles for the references to be correct.

It would also have been possible to patch `\footnotemark` with [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) rather than copying the original definition from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls).

Caveat: This approach is not compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: Thank you @Werner. That is a very clever solution. I must ask what \the means. I compiled your document and it worked fine, however, when I copied the same definitions to another input file, I received the following error: "! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> \protect." In the output file, numbering for normal \footnote{} commands and \footnotemark commands are unaffected, but \footnotetext commands produce a footnote number of 0. I am concerned that fnmarkcntr and fntextcntr may have become dissociated from one another.

Comment: When preceding a counter `fnmarkcntr` with `\the` (as in `\thefnmarkcntr`) it typesets the counter in its currently defined form (say `\arabic` or `\alph` or `\Roman`...). Try and see if you can incorporate my definition(s) with yours into an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to clearly shows the problem you are experiencing. There may be many things influencing my proposed solution, including your `\documentclass` as well as other packages. Edit your question and include this MWE as part of it.

Comment: @Werner Hyperref can produce some nasty errors... as it is beyond the scope to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`... (from the manual). I recommend `hyperfootnotes=false`. This is what probably is causing the errors.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: That's true. The original question didn't mention anything about `hyperref`. As such, I'll see if there's anything that can be done to save this answer. Otherwise, I'll suggest opening a new one (as a follow-up) that should rectify any incompatibilities with `hyperref`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Thank you for your comment.
@Werner: Thank you for posting a helpful solution. Please let me know if you find any solution to the `hyperref`-induced error.

Comment: @Werner I also missed to read it the first time I read the question... is at the bottom ...I would like to be able to include hyperlinks in my footnotes. Maybe you want to add a caveat in your answer.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Will do...

Comment: @Werner: could you explain this line: `\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}` and these commands: `\@xfootnotemark` and `\@footnotemark`. For instance what is the purpose of the 'x'? Thanks.

Comment: @user001: This definition of `\footnotemark` comes directly from the file [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) which contains all the information (macros, lengths and environments) associated with the `article` document class. A similar definition is contained within [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls). As such, `\@xfootnotemark` and `\@footnotemark` are both macros that are called from within `\footnotemark`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. I wasn't able to find these definitions in article.cls, either in [the file you linked to](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) or in my own system's article.cls (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls). I must be looking in the wrong place.