# The \the command

Tags: macros

I wanted to know if someone could point me to a reference where I could learn more about the `\the` command. Searching for "the" has been, without surprise, entirely unproductive. Even consulting "comprehensive" LaTeX command/macro lists has been unfruitful.

[This blog](http://texblog.org/2011/05/07/the-command/) is the only treatment of the subject that I could find, but it was not very informative.

Comment: I don't know where you searched, but there is [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0201134470) by [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Comment: How is finding this question going to be easier now? :D

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Could we add some tag like [tag:tex-core] or [tag:latex-kernel] here? I don't know what part comes from where, but `\the` must come from somewhere. (Feel free to delete this comment of mine later.)

Comment: @badp Hello from 12 years in the future - I am happy to report that this question is now the first result I see in Google when searching for "latex \the" (without quotes).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

## The mighty `\the`

TeX has many registers and internal parameters, whose list can be found in the TeXbook (supplemented by the e-TeX manual and the pdftex manual, for the respective extensions; many more internal parameters are introduced by XeTeX and LuaTeX).

In general, `\the\something` extracts a representation of the value assigned to `\something`; the assignment can be explicit (`\dimen100=2cm`) or implicit (`\year` is assigned its value at the beginning of the TeX run), in some cases the parameter is "read only" (`\badness`) and the value stored in it has been assigned during processing.

### Registers

In what follows, `\something` stands for a register of the analyzed type; for example, after `\newcount\pippo` one can say `\the\pippo`, or it's an explicitly mentioned register such as `\count100` or `\dimen0`.

1. `\count`: `\the\something` extracts the counter's value representation as a number in base 10
2. `\dimen`: `\the\something` extracts the stored length representation with unit "typographic point" (`pt`) as a decimal number, always with at least a digit after the decimal point; for example, after `\dimen0=2pt`, `\the\dimen0` will produce `2.0pt`
3. `\skip`: almost the same as before, but with the additional `plus` and `minus` parts (which are omitted if zero)
4. `\muskip`: the same as `\skip`, but the units are in `mu`
5. `\toks`: this is a *very* special case, see later
6. `\box`: also this is a special case, as `\the\box0` is *illegal* (the contents of box registers is accessed at with `\box`, `\copy` and related commands such as `\unhbox`)

### Internal parameters

One can use `\the\something` where `\something` is an internal parameter; for example, `\the\tolerance` will behave just like case 1, `\the\parindent` like in case 2, `\the\baselineskip` as in case 3, `\the\thinmuskip` as in case 4, `\the\everypar` as in case 5. Similarly, `\the\day`, `\the\month`, `\the\year` and `\the\time` will print the values these internal parameters have been automatically assigned at the start of the job (or modified afterwards). Note that `\time` is assigned the number of minutes past midnight when the job started (as determined by asking the operating system).

### Internal tables

TeX maintains some tables (or vectors): the `\catcode` table for category codes; the `\uccode` and `\lccode` tables for uppercase-lowercase conversion; the `\sffcode` table for space factors; the `\mathcode` table for deciding the nature of a character in math mode; the `\delcode` table for deciding what to do if a character is encountered when TeX is looking for a math fence. In all these cases,

```
\the<tablename><number>
```

produces the stored value in place `<number>` of the vector; the vector's length is 256 in the case of (pdf)TeX, 2^21 in the case of XeTeX and LuaTeX. For example,

```
\the\catcode123 \the\lccode65
```

will produce respectively `1` and `97` (with standard settings); of course, the `<number>` can be expressed in other ways (as octal or hexadecimal number, or as an alphabetical constant). For (pdf)TeX the `<number>` must be from 0 to 255; for XeTeX and LuaTeX from 0 to 2097151 (hexadecimal `0x1FFFFF`).

### Special uses

`\the` can also go before other tokens.

- If we've said `\chardef\pippo=37`, then `\the\pippo` will produce `37`; similarly for `\mathchardef`. The representation will be a number in base 10.
- `\the\font` produces a control sequence that corresponds to the command for selecting the current font; therefore, `\xdef\pippo{\the\font}` will globally define the command `\pippo` that will select the font current at the time of `\xdef`.
- `\the\hyphenchar\font`, `\the\skewchar\font`, `\the\fontdimen<number>\font` will extract the corresponding information for the current font; instead of `\font` one can use any font selecting command (such as `\tenrm` in Plain TeX or `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` in LaTeX). For example,

  ```
  \the\fontdimen2\csname OT1/cmr/m/n/10\endcsname
  ```

  will make available the normal interword space for the mentioned font (which is 3.33333pt).
- `\the<token register>` will produce (a copy of) the token list contained in the `<token register>`; also internal tokens variables can be used: `\the\everypar` will produce the token list contained in the stated variable.

Only in the cases of `\the\font` (but instead of `\font` can go any font selecting command) and `\the<token register>` or `\the<internal token variable>` TeX produces something which is not a string of characters.

When `\the` produces a string of characters, they will all have category code 12, excepts spaces that receive category code 10.

### Important notes

1. `\the` *is* expandable. So, while `\def\pippo{\count100}` and `\edef\pippo{\count100}` are completely equivalent, `\edef\pippo{\the\count100}` will define `\pippo` as the *current* register's value. If we want to store away the current chapter number in LaTeX, we say `\edef\thischapternumber{\the\value{chapter}}`.
2. `\the` will perform expansion on the token following it, stopping only when the next token is a legal one which `\the` can be applied to. So `\the\value{chapter}` is possible, as `\value{chapter}` expands to `\csname c@chapter\endcsname` and then to `\c@chapter` (that is a count register defined via `\countdef`).
3. `\the` is sometimes superfluous. For example, if we want to keep the current category code of `@`, in order to restore it after some processing, we might say

   ```
   \edef\currentatcatcode{\the\catcode`\@}
   ```

   but there's a more efficient way:

   ```
   \chardef\currentatcatcode=\catcode`\@
   ```

   Similarly, if we want to take different actions when the badness of the last produced box is less than 5000 or greater than 5000, we can say

   ```
   \ifnum\badness<5000
      \dosomething
   \else
      \dosomethingelse
   \fi
   ```

   Similarly, to set `\parindent` to the value stored in `\normalparindent` (a `\dimen` register allocated in advance), we don't say

   ```
   \parindent=\the\normalparindent
   ```

   but use the easier

   ```
   \parindent=\normalparindent
   ```

Comment: @egreg Nicely detailed answer. Why does `\the` not work with dimension registers? e.g. from `fancyhdr`,`\the\headrulewidth`? I get `! You can't use the \`character 0' after \the.` where 0 can be any digit, the initial character in the dimension definition e.g. `0pt`.

Comment: @macmadness86 `\headrulewidth` is a macro, not a dimension register. If you check in the manual of `fancyhdr`, you see that you have to do `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{<dimen>}` for changing its value.

Comment: @macmadness86 You should realize that when `fancyheadings` (the predecessor of `fancyhdr`) was being developed, registers were in much shorter supply than they're nowadays and it was very common to spare on them using macros when referring to length that aren't to be manipulated, but just used.

Comment: @egreg Ah, you mean 2^8 (256) registers rather than the 2^16 (65536) as of `etex`. I figured it was something like that. Several illogical things stem from limitations in TeX.

Answer (score 43):

The `\the` primitive is provided by the underlying TeX not by the higher-level LaTeX, therefore it is normally not discussed by LaTeX texts. You would need to read a TeX book like *The TeXBook* or one of the [free TeX books available](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ol-books) like [*TeX by Topic* (chapters 12 and 14)](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html), or maybe a LaTeX book which explicitly discusses this deeper concepts.

In short `\the` can only be used in front of a register, either `dimen`, `skip` (e.g. a LaTeX length), `muskip`, `count` (the underlying register for LaTeX counters) and other numeric expressions like `\catcode<number>` or `toks` (token register) as well as special font macros like `\font` (and maybe others I forget now) and then expands this register to its value in string form. For example `\the\textwidth` will expand to a string representation of the current text width like `345.0pt`.
This is useful for writing such information to auxiliary files, print them as part of the document (for e.g. debugging) and for internal conversions.

---

Here the entry from the free book *TeX for the Impatient*, page 254f:

`\the <token>`
This command generally expands to a list of character tokens that represents
`<token>`. `<token>` can be any of the following:

- a TeX parameter, e.g., `\parindent` or `\deadcycles`
- a register, e.g., `\count0`
- a code associated with an input character, e.g., `\catcode‘(`
- a font parameter, e.g., `\fontdimen3\sevenbf`
- the `\hyphenchar` or `\skewchar` of a font, e.g., `\skewchar\teni`
  `\lastpenalty`, `\lastskip`, or `\lastkern` (values derived from the
  last item on the current horizontal or vertical list)
- a control sequence defined by `\chardef` or `\mathchardef`

In addition, `\the` can expand to noncharacter tokens in the following two
cases:

- `\the <font>`, which expands to the most recently defined control sequence
  that selects the same font as the control sequence `<font>`
- `\the <token variable>`, which expands to a copy of the value of the
  variable, e.g., `\the\everypar`

Comment: Great answer. I've seen `\the`<token> with no space between `\the` and the ensuing token. For instance, to tokenize a counter named `cntr`, the expression `\thecntr` is handled without issue. I'm wondering why the TeX processor does not require a space and how it is able to interpret that `\thecntr` really means `\the cntr`. Thanks.

Comment: @user001: Note that `\thecntr` is just a macro with the name `thecntr`, it doesn't use `\the`. The name is just used because it resembles the same meaning.

Comment: So in the [solution by @Werner to a question I posted about nested footnoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38652/10127), there are several instances of \the being directly followed, without whitespace, by various tokens. It appears that these do not represent unique macros, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @user001: They are all own macros. The `\newcounter` macro creates them.