# Custom theorem numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

This one should be easy for the gurus…

Suppose I want to define a theorem environment which has a custom numbering scheme. That is, instead of being numbered according to some counter, it is numbered according to a passed parameter. So writing something like

```
\begin{customtheorem}{8}
   Text.
\end{custom theorem}
```

would produce

**Theorem 8.** Text.

I realize I could define a new environment on my own, but then the header will be bold, or small caps, or whatever I defined it to be, and so may differ from the rest of the document if I switch documentclass. So I would like something that also matches the regular theorem headers.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

An easy way is

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsthm} %% uncomment to see the difference
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
  {\endinnercustomthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{customthm}{8}\label{eight}
Every theorem must be numbered by hand.
\end{customthm}

Here is a reference to theorem~\ref{eight}.
\end{document}
```

You can also use the optional argument for attribution:

```
\begin{customthm}{99}[Somebody]\label{ninetynine}
Statement.
\end{customthm}
```

---

A more generic interface for defining several of these environments; this doesn't respect theorem styles; it could be adapted, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}
}

\newcustomtheorem{customthm}{Theorem}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{customthm}{8}\label{eight}
Every theorem must be numbered by hand.
\end{customthm}

Here is a reference to theorem~\ref{eight} and
one to the important lemma~\ref{life-universe-everything}

\begin{customlemma}{42}\label{life-universe-everything}
This lemma explains everything.
\end{customlemma}


\end{document}
```

[image]

#### ADDITION

Support for `cleveref` was asked in comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \ifdefined\crefalias\crefalias{innercustomgeneric}{#2}\fi
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}%
  \ifdefined\crefname\crefname{#2}{#2}{#2s}\fi
}

\newcustomtheorem{customthm}{Theorem}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{customthm}{8}\label{eight}
Every theorem must be numbered by hand.
\end{customthm}

Here is a reference to \cref{eight} and
one to the important \cref{life-universe-everything}

\begin{customlemma}{42}\label{life-universe-everything}
This lemma explains everything.
\end{customlemma}

\end{document}
```

The `\ifdefined` bits allow for the solution to be independent on `cleveref`.

[image]

Comment: I guess that's simpler than mine (and allows non numeric values too)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it uses the fact that `innercustomthm` is stepped, so the reference is established, but `\theinnercustomthm` is used, which can contain anything (well, almost).

Comment: This is splendid. Thanks so much.

@DavidCarlisle: I went with egreg's, because it's simpler, but thanks also!

Comment: I am interested in an extension of this behavior.  Let's say I want to create a theorem with the same label as a previous theorem.  I would like to display this as `\begin{customthm}{\ref{oldtheorem}}\end{customthm}`, but this gives me errors.  How would I modify this code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The optional argument form did not work for me (I'm using amsthm). I fixed this with `\newenvironment{customthm}[2][]{\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#2}\innercustomthm[#1]}{\endinnercustomthm}`.

Comment: @egreg may I ask what is the merits of "somebody"?

Comment: @egreg and is it possible to extend this to definition, lemma?

Comment: @athos `\newtheorem{innercustomlemma}{Lemma}` and `\newenvironment{customlemma}[1]{\renewcommand\theinnercustomlemma{#1}\innercustomlemma}{\endinnercustomlemma}`

Comment: @egreg the error says "undefined control sequence"....

Comment: What undefined control sequence?

Comment: @egreg I added "\newtheorem{innercustomlemma}{Lemma}  \newenvironment{customlemma}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomlemma{#1}\innercust‌​omlemma}
  {\endinnercustomlemma}" at the beginning then "\begin{customlemma}{abc}[abcd]\label{abcde}
abcdef
\end{customthm}" at the body. The error says: "! Undefined control sequence.
\customlemma ...heinnercustomlemma {#1}\innercust XXXXX
                                                  ‌​omlemma
l.126 \begin{customlemma}{abc} XXXXX
                              [abcd]\label{abcde}
? " here XXXXX is the line break.

Comment: @egreg one more question -- is it possible to "tune off" the italic font used for theorems?

Comment: @athos Can you please open a new question linking to this one?

Comment: @egreg i've posted it in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187971/custom-theorem-numbering-and-extend-to-lemma-etc

Comment: @egreg I am trying to set counter for both of my lemmas and theorems. So I copy and paste your code "\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
  {\endinnercustomthm}" again, and change the "Theorem" to "Lemma". However, I found that all of my lemmas become theorems. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with that....

Comment: @KevinKim You have to define two environments for each type, or use two arguments. I'll add it later.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, this answer is great! I just have a follow-up question: Is it possible to make the number of the theorem differ from the number that is printed in references to it? For example, if I do `\begin{customthm}{8}{-5}\label{abc} blabla \end{customthm}`, I would like the theorem number to be 8, but if I do `\ref{abc}`, I would like -5 to be printed.

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm not sure why you'd like to do that. You can do `\makeatletter\newcommand\manuallabel[1]{\def\@currentlabel{#1}}\makeatletter` and use `\begin{customthm}{8}\manuallabel{-5}\label{abc}`

Comment: @egreg: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! If you really want to know why I want to do this, read on: For a certain reason, I want to have a Theorem with the number 16.9\frac{1}{2}. But since (at least in amsart) the theorem number is set in bold, I use `\frac{\boldsymbol{1}}{\boldsymbol{2}}`. However, in references to the theorem, I would like the usual `\frac{1}{2}` instead of the bold fraction :)

Comment: @PhoemueX Naughty boy!

Comment: Hi @egreg I am trying to adapt this code to acknowledge theorem styles, but I'm not able to make sufficient sense of the underlying logic do pull this off. Do you know of where I can go to understand how the \the[innercustomgeneric] and \end[innercustomgeneric] are working here? I found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command but I'm having trouble figuring out how that articulates with what you are doing here.

Comment: @benblumsmith You need to define an “inner” environment for each style you want to use. The command `\the` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @egreg I was making an attempt to parse the logic of your code in order to be able to see what I was doing when adapting it. I think the \the is my primary obstruction to parsing the logic, which is why I asked about it. I have a temporary workaround so I guess I'll just let this go for now.

Comment: This works fine to restate theorems. I know there are packages specifically for that. But, I prefer this for practical reasons (eg: less chance of package conflicts).

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this play nice with the `restatable` environment from `thmtools` package? That is, I want to make a custom-numbered theorem restatable.  I can't figure out how to get the restatable environment to understand why I'm giving it an extra argument (namely, the number that I want to assign to the theorem)

Comment: A disadvantage of this solution is that is doesn’t appear to work with `cleveref`.

Comment: @HermeticallySealedHalibut Added support for `cleveref`

Answer (score 14):

You can just temporarily reset your theorem counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}



\makeatletter

\newenvironment{customTheorem}[1]
  {\count@\c@Theorem
   \global\c@Theorem#1 %
    \global\advance\c@Theorem\m@ne
   \Theorem}
  {\endTheorem
   \global\c@Theorem\count@}

\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{Theorem}
Dummy text
\end{Theorem}

\begin{customTheorem}{99}
Dummy text
\end{customTheorem}

\begin{Theorem}
Dummy text
\end{Theorem}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way if it's just for a few theorems is

```
\newtheorem*{theorem8}{Theorem 8}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for, since it's not using a parameter to the environment, but it solved a problem of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way suitable for a few theorems, but technically not addressing the exact question, as it doesn't define a new environment.

Immediately before declaring the theorem, reset the counter to the number preceding the one you want.

```latex
% For Theorem 9, with the default counter named "theorem"
\setcounter{theorem}{8}

% Now declare the theorem
\begin{Theorem}
Dummy text
\end{Theorem}
```