# Custom theorem numbering ... and extend to lemma etc

Tags: numbering, theorems

In [Custom theorem numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53978/custom-theorem-numbering/53981?noredirect=1#comment435397_53981) @egreg provided a way to custome theorem numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsthm} %% uncomment to see the difference
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
  {\endinnercustomthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{customthm}{8}[Somebody]\label{eight}
Every theorem must be numbered by hand.
\end{customthm}

Here is a reference to theorem~\ref{eight}.
\end{document}
```

Now I tend to extend such approach to Lemma, Definition, Corollary etc. However I got an error extending to Lemma.

I put in

```
\newtheorem{innercustomlemma}{Lemma}
\newenvironment{customlemma}[1] 
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomlemma{#1}\innercust‌​omlemma} 
  {\endinnercustomlemma}
```

at the beginning then

```
\begin{customlemma}{abc}[abcd]\label{abcde} 
  abcdef 
\end{customthm}
```

at the body. The error says:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \customlemma ...heinnercustomlemma {#1}\innercust 
                                                                                omlemma 
l.126 \begin{customlemma}{abc} 
                                 [abcd]\label{abcde} ?
```

I wonder what shall I do?

Also, the font inside theorem is italic by default, I wonder if this could be tuned off?

Comment: You have two spurious characters in `\innercustomlemma`; you can see in the question that `\innercust` is rendered in brown color, while `omlemma` is black. Retype it.

Comment: @egreg exactly! it's working now. -- any idea to turn off the italic font?

Comment: Uncomment `\usepackage{amsthm}` and add `\theoremstyle{definition}` before the first `\newtheorem` command. But don't do it.

Comment: @egreg may i ask why?

Comment: It's customary to set theorem statements in italics to make them more visible to the reader.

Comment: @egreg ah then I have no concern -- I'm writing a study notes for myself , so it's full of theorems , lemmas, and definitions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem simply due to spurious invisible characters in the input.