# Custom theorem numbering italicized

Tags: numbering, theorems

In [Custom theorem numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53978/custom-theorem-numbering/53981?noredirect=1#comment435397_53981) @egreg gave us a way to put custom labels on theorems. However, when I compile my latex document with that new command, the text of the theorem is in regular text. If I want it to be in italicized text, how should I modify the command?

EDIT: At the top of my latex document, I have

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,verbatim,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd, graphicx,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, cd, backgrounds}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\topmargin0.0cm
\headheight0.0cm
\headsep0.0cm
\oddsidemargin0.0cm
\textheight23.0cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\footskip1.0cm
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem*{question}{Question} 
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
{\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
{\endinnercustomthm}
\begin{document}
```

Then, when I insert a theorem using "\begin{theorem}," the compiled version is italicized. Now, I wanted to use the custom numbering system outlined in the link. But when I followed that answer, the resulting text is not italicized.

If I write

```
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
```

I get

**Theorem 1.** *This is a theorem.*

But if I type the newcommand at the top

```
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
{\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
{\endinnercustomthm}
```

and then I type

```
\begin{customthm}{1.1}
This is a theorem.
\end{custom}
```

I get

**Theorem 1.1.** This is a theorem.

I want the body of the text to be italicized.

EDIT 2: I added the header of the document. Sorry about my ignorance-I copied the header from a template but I don't know the details about how to tweak it.

Comment: If I recompile the very example, I get the text of the theorem in italics. Maybe you have `\theoremstyle{definition}` before declaring the new theorem?

Comment: @egreg: I think the O.P. means the numbering which is not in italics

Comment: Please, clarify your request.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont' get this. Please, add a minimal example starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Move the four lines preceding `\begin{document}` before the line `\theoremstyle{definition}`. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the most recent `\theoremstyle` call before `\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}` is `\theoremstyle{definition}`, so `innercustomthm` takes on the style of a definition, i.e. upright text. You can fix this by moving `\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}` before all of your other theorem declarations, which will give it the default italic style.

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
 % ... other theorem declarations (same as before)
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
{\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
{\endinnercustomthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{customthm}{1.1}
This is a theorem.
\end{customthm}
\end{document}
```

[image]