# Two solutions to one problem

Tags: environments, theorems

I have defined the solution environment as below:

```
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[subsection]
```

I have two solutions to problem 1.3.3 as shown in the attached screenshot. However, by using `\begin{solution} \end{solution}` twice, the second solution would be named as 1.3.4. Is there any way to change the counter so that these two solutions both correspond to the same question? Something like 1.3.3-1 & 1.3.3-2 would be great, but if there's a more elegant way, I'd also love to hear it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There are several packages for formatting problems and their solutions, perhaps one such is a better match than (ab)using theorems for this task...

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using `amsthm` to manage your theorems. In that case you can set the parent counter of your `solution` environment to be the counter of your theorem, like so

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[thm]
% ^^^ Note that as <parent counter> we are using
%     the thm counter 

\begin{document}
  \section{Sec 1}
  \subsection{Subsec 1}
  \begin{thm}
    Test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{solution}
    Sol 1
  \end{solution}
  \begin{solution}
    Sol 2
  \end{solution}

  \section{Sec 2}
  \subsection{Subsec 2}
  \begin{thm}
    Test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{solution}
    Sol 1
  \end{solution}
  \begin{solution}
    Sol 2
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image: solution]

Comment: This works, thanks! One question remains — would it be possible to set the counter like this only when I need it for a problem with more than one solution? Because now if I were to do this, every solution has the format of "1.1.1.1", but I'd love to make them "1.1.1.1" only when there's a need for "1.1.1.2" and leave them as "1.1.1" when there's no such need.

Comment: One immediate solution would be to just simply create a different environment, like `singleSolution` that has the counter set to `subsection`. That would definitely do it for you. If you want only one... I'm not really sure to be quite honest. I will try and find a solution tomorrow, until then let's hope more experienced TeXers come and help us :)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53978/custom-theorem-numbering Quite interesting way, but I believe there gotta be a more elegant way :D

Comment: I feel like the other answer does what you want in a neater way. Too bad for the referencing issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following example should work to number solutions within problems only when there are multiple solutions to the same problem. It basically works by defining a command which stores the number of solutions to a given problem in the `.aux` file, and by redefining the `\thesolution` command to display the number of the solution according to the number of solutions to the problem. It's a little complicated, and maybe there's a simpler way to do that, but I couldn't think of any.

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}
\newcounter{numsolution}
\numberwithin{numsolution}{problem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{problem}{%
    \addtocounter{problem}{1}
    \newcounter{solsofprob\the\value{section}.\the\value{subsection}.\the\value{problem}}
    \addtocounter{problem}{-1}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
    \addtocounter{solsofprob\the\value{section}.\the\value{subsection}.\the\value{problem}}{1}
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\numsolsofprob\romannumeral\the\value{section}@\romannumeral\the\value{subsection}@\romannumeral\the\value{problem}{\the\value{solsofprob\the\value{section}.\the\value{subsection}.\the\value{problem}}}}%
}
\newcommand{\tempnum}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesolution}{%
    \@ifundefined{numsolsofprob\romannumeral\the\value{section}@\romannumeral\the\value{subsection}@\romannumeral\the\value{problem}}%
        {\def\tempnum{0}}%
        {\edef\tempnum{\csname numsolsofprob\romannumeral\the\value{section}@\romannumeral\the\value{subsection}@\romannumeral\the\value{problem}\endcsname}}%
    \ifnum \tempnum > 1
        \stepcounter{numsolution}%
        \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{problem}--\arabic{numsolution}%
    \else
        \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{problem}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{problem}
    A problem.
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
    The solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{problem}
    Another problem. 
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
    A first solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}
    A second solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{problem}
    Another problem.
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
    A solution.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{problem}
    A problem.
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
    A solution.
\end{solution}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{problem}
    A problem.
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
    A solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}
    Another solution.
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

The above codes outputs:
[image]

I should also mention that, since this solution works by redefining the `\thesolution` command in a complicated way, it will not be possible to add a label to a solution to reference it later. I will update the code if I think of something to make to labeling work.

Comment: Well, we can always refer to the problem instead, and that won't give us too much extra work to scroll down to the solution :) Inspired by @gjkf , I tried to do two separate commands ``\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}[subsection]`` and ``\newtheorem{subsolution}{Solution}[problem]`` which also works. But I love this little dash more! Thanks.