# Custom Environment Numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to achieve a goal *extremely* similar to that requested in [Custom theorem numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53978/custom-theorem-numbering).
There [egreg explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53981/81928) how to create a custom theorem environment. However, one must specify whether it is to be a Theorem, Proposition or whatever. He uses the following code.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}
}

\newcustomtheorem{customthm}{Theorem}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
```

I would not like to make this final decision, but rather have an environment `customgen` which when called with `title` uses that title. Consider the following, using egreg's command.

```
\begin{customthm}{CUSTOM_LABEL}
    This is Theorem CUSTOM_LABEL
\end{customthm}
```

This creates an environment which starts `Theorem CUSTOM_LABEL`. I would like

```
\begin{customgen}{CUSTOM_TITLE}
   This may or may not be a theorem
\end{customgen}
```

to start `CUSTOM_TITLE`.

I can nearly achieve this by replacing the `[2]` with `[1]` and commenting out the command `\renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}`. However, there is extra whitespace on the left. I don't know how to get rid of that.

Comment: Do you want numbering?

Comment: No numbering---the `CUSTOM_TITLE` is all that I need. I see why you would ask, though. And your answer gives both options!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{customthminner}{\customthmname}[section]
\newcommand{\customthmname}{}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\customthmname}{#1}\customthminner}
 {\endcustomthminner}

\begin{document}

\section{Famous theorems}

\begin{customthm}{Gauss's lemma}
Blah blah
\end{customthm}

\begin{customthm}{Fermat's last theorem}
Blah blah
\end{customthm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want numbering, use `\newtheorem*` (and no optional argument).

Comment: I see, thanks. I expected that something simpler would work, I just couldn't make it work myself!