# How to use cleveref (or other alternatives) with a custom theorem environment to reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, labels, cleveref

In this post [Custom theorem numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53978/custom-theorem-numbering) there is an explanation by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53981/122021) that shows how to implement this. Now I would like to be able to reference so that I would not have to type lemma/proposition etc. right before `\ref{}` when referring to a particular `\label{}` because by using `\ref{}` it only gives the numbering. However, using the `cref{}` from the cleveref package only gives question marks on the page after compilation (which I'm not surprised about since it's a package independent of the code given by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53981/122021)). How does one solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

%===========================================================%
%The code below customises theorem numbering
%===========================================================%
\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}  
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}
}


\newcustomtheorem{customdefinition}{Definition}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
\newcustomtheorem{customproposition}{Proposition}
%===========================================================%

\begin{document}

\begin{customproposition}{5.2} \label{hello}
blah blah 
\end{customproposition}

I want to Proposition \ref{hello} without 
having to type proposition 
at the beginning of \ref{hello}.



\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an efficient and clean way to do this? Either via cleveref or other alternatives by writing a particular code to reference `\label{}` without having to write "Proposition" in front of the reference?

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full bit minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add stuff in order to even compile your code and then a lot of people will not bother with tour question.

Comment: Hello. Please make a full compilable document starting with `\documentclass{}`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! Hope that helps.

Comment: Does `\crefname{customproposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}` after calling the package `cleverref` help you? I currently can't test it myself.

Comment: @Lukas Thanks for the reply. No sorry since it's not a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `cleveref` type and alias the counter.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

%===========================================================%
%The code below customises theorem numbering
%===========================================================%
\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}  
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \crefname{#2}{#2}{#2s}%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \crefalias{innercustomgeneric}{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}
}


\newcustomtheorem{customdefinition}{Definition}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
\newcustomtheorem{customproposition}{Proposition}
%===========================================================%

\begin{document}

\begin{customproposition}{5.2} \label{hello}
blah blah 
\end{customproposition}

\begin{customdefinition}{12.4} \label{helloagain}
blah blah 
\end{customdefinition}

I want \cref{hello} without having to type ``proposition''.

Also \cref{helloagain}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just as desired! On another note, would you happen to know where a beginner could read up about how to devise a code like this? I obviously don't how it works since I don't even know what 'type' and 'alias' and 'counter' are.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Defined a `new command \pref`, which "prints" "Proposition" and the \ref .

Remarks: also works when you use labels like this `environment:label` (like `fig:drawing`), which is useful once you've got many different types of environments.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

%===========================================================%
%The code below customises theorem numbering
%===========================================================%
\newtheorem{innercustomgeneric}{\customgenericname}  
\providecommand{\customgenericname}{}
\newcommand{\newcustomtheorem}[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#1}[1]
  {%
   \renewcommand\customgenericname{#2}%
   \renewcommand\theinnercustomgeneric{##1}%
   \innercustomgeneric
  }
  {\endinnercustomgeneric}
}


\newcustomtheorem{customdefinition}{Definition}
\newcustomtheorem{customlemma}{Lemma}
\newcustomtheorem{customproposition}{Proposition}
%~~~ new ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~% <<==
\newcommand{\pref}[1]{Proposition \ref{#1}}
%===========================================================%

\begin{document}

\begin{customproposition}{5.2} \label{hello}
blah blah 
\end{customproposition}

I want to Proposition \ref{hello} without 
having to type proposition 
at the beginning of \ref{hello}. \\

Is this the way you want to make a call to \pref{hello}?% <<==

\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I would like it to work for any \customtheorem{} I define in the preamble. So when I call \ref{} on the \label it does it accordingly without having to define it for each \customtheorem{}.

Comment: Sorry, don't get what you want. I suggest to edit your question and to put a clarifying example at the end.