# nameref, ref, and other issues with referencing back

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I amm having issues with `\nameref` and `\ref` not returning the desired output. I would like to have definitions referred to by Definition 0.0.1 (see below). I do not want the result of \nameref{defn1} to be bold and I would like the "Definition" to appear. More precisely, here is the output (via overleaf):

[image]

Here is the relevant TeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, reqno,openany]{amsbook}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black, citecolor=magenta, linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\makeatletter
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\def\@secnumfont{\mdseries}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%\
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headfont{\scshape}}{\thm@headfont{\bfseries}}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{\textbf{Theorem}}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{\textbf{Definition}}
\newtheorem{conv}[thm]{\textbf{Convention}}
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{\textbf{Remark}}
\newtheorem{crmk}[thm]{\textbf{Cautionary Remark}}
\newtheorem{notn}[thm]{\textbf{Notation}}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{\text{Example}}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\textbf{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{\textbf{Proposition}}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{\textbf{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{q}[thm]{\textbf{Question}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{defn}}}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{thm}}}
\renewcommand{\theconv}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{conv}}}
\renewcommand{\thermk}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{rmk}}}
\renewcommand{\thecrmk}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{crmk}}}
\renewcommand{\thenotn}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{notn}}}
\renewcommand{\theex}{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{ex}}
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{prop}}}
\renewcommand{\thecor}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{cor}}}
\renewcommand{\thelem}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{lem}}}
\renewcommand{\theq}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{q}}}
\begin{document}

Consider the following:

\begin{ex}\label{example1}
Here is an example.
\end{ex}

Hence, define:

\begin{defn}\label{defn1}
We make the following definition.
\end{defn}

If I want to refer back to these, nameref does not yield anything: \nameref{example1} (Package hyperref warning: suppressing empty link).  On the other hand, ref simply returns the number, e.g., \ref{defn1}. \\

I would like the reference to the example (respectively, definition) to appear as Example 0.0.1 (respectively, Definition 0.0.2).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616569/how-to-use-cleveref-or-other-alternatives-with-a-custom-theorem-environment-to) could help you set up a custom label for references (also: your LaTeX code is missing a `\documentclass`).

Comment: @Miyase Thank you for your comment. I'll look at the answer to that question. Thanks for pointing out the absence of the document class, that should be fixed now :-)

Comment: `\nameref` returns the title, not the number. So with `\begin{defn}[Famous definition]` you get Famous definition from it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment. This produces the undesired "Famous definition" next to Definition 1.1.1., however.

Comment: @Miyase I've looked over that example in that answer that you reference, but I'm still not seeing how this gives the desired result. I'm only getting the label without the definition or number component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with cleveref:

```
\documentclass[11pt, reqno,openany]{amsbook}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black, citecolor=magenta, linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
% From @egreg : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609191/120578
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@cref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\makeatletter
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\def\@secnumfont{\mdseries}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%\
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headfont{\scshape}}{\thm@headfont{\bfseries}}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conv}[thm]{Convention}
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{crmk}[thm]{Cautionary Remark}
\newtheorem{notn}[thm]{Notation}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{q}[thm]{Question}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{defn}}}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{thm}}}
\renewcommand{\theconv}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{conv}}}
\renewcommand{\thermk}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{rmk}}}
\renewcommand{\thecrmk}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{crmk}}}
\renewcommand{\thenotn}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{notn}}}
\renewcommand{\theex}{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{ex}}
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{prop}}}
\renewcommand{\thecor}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{cor}}}
\renewcommand{\thelem}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{lem}}}
\renewcommand{\theq}{\textbf{\thesection.\thesubsection \arabic{q}}}
\begin{document}

Consider the following:

\begin{ex}\label{example1}
Here is an example.
\end{ex}

Hence, define:

\begin{defn}\label{defn1}
We make the following definition.
\end{defn}

If I want to refer back to these, nameref does not yield anything: \Cref{example1} %[NOW IT WORKS] 
(Package hyperref warning: suppressing empty link).  On the other hand, ref simply returns the number, e.g., \ref{defn1}. \\

I would like the reference to the example (respectively, definition) to appear as Example 0.0.1 (respectively, Definition 0.0.2).

\end{document}
```

I have removed all the `\textbf{}`s (I used @egregs way for making bold) from the newtheorem commands and I used just `\Cref`command from the package `cleveref`...

Output:

[image]

Comment: Feel free to remove all the `\textbf{}`s ...