# Add Custom Theorem Number Between Two Theorems

Tags: counters, amsthm

I hope this question is not a duplicate, I found many questions regarding theorem numbering in amsthm but none that addressed this problem.

I'm writing down handwritten lecture notes in LaTeX using an environment created with `\newtheorem`. My professor added a *Theorem 3'* between Theorem 3 and Theorem 4, what is the quickest way to add a custom label for this theorem and then continue numbering with Theorem 4, Theorem 5, ... ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53980/205359

Comment: If I understood this right this only allows numbers not custom strings like `3'` but the downvoted answer there might work for my usecase.