# How can I know the default PGF line width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rules, lengths

Is there some macro that will tell me what the default PGF line width is? I have tried creating my own macro by cloning `\pgflinewidth` before it has been modified, i.e.

```
\let\defaultlinewidth\pgflinewidth
```

but `\defaultlinewidth` seems to be affected by `\pgfsetlinewidth` anyway, and change to whatever `\pgflinewidth` is. So, the problem is that after I have called `\pgfsetlinewidth`, I don't know what the default pgf line width is anymore. Is there some way to get around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\pgflinewidth` is a length. So you can use `\setlength` to copy its current value:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\defaultpgflinewidth}
\setlength{\defaultpgflinewidth}{\pgflinewidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \draw circle [radius=1cm];
  \draw[line width=\defaultpgflinewidth] (-1cm,-1cm) rectangle (1cm,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** (suggestion from  Christian Feuersänger)

You can also use `\edef` to make a copy of the current representation of this length.

```
 \edef\defaultpgflinewidth{\the\pgflinewidth}
```

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for. :) So it is `\setlength` you have to use to copy a length, do you know why `\let` doesn't work?

Comment: `\let` will create another name for the same dimen register. It is like creating a new pointer to the same object. But you want a copy, not a reference - in that case, you can use the `\setlength` solution (as here, although this might waste a TeX register) or you use `\edef\defaultpgflinewidth{\the\pgflinewidth}` which will also store a copy (but into a cheap macro).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Good suggestion. I will edit my answer to add it.

Comment: @Paul: Can you also use the `\edef` solution if you would want to define a length that is a factor a length, for example `1.5\pgflinewidth`? I have tried `\edef\mylength{1.5\the\pgflinewidth}` and `\edef\mylength{\the{1.5\pgflinewidth}}` but both of those give me an error. `\setlength` still works fine, though.

Comment: Here's a link to a different question - but the answer is related, as it explains the mechanisms behind `\pgflinewidth`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185163/reading-and-effect-of-default-tikz-pgf-keys/185170#185170

Answer (score 33):

You can always query PGF directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \width [count=\yi] in {ultra thin,very thin,thin,semithick, thick, very thick, ultra thick}
  \node[\width] at (0,-0.5*\yi) {The value with the \texttt{\width} option is \the\pgflinewidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a similar way, you can define a command to keep the default value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\defvalue{%
  \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[line width=\pgflinewidth] {The default value is \the\pgflinewidth};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}
\draw (0,3ex) -- (1,3ex);
\node at (6,3ex) {The current value is \the\pgflinewidth. \defvalue};
\pgfsetlinewidth{3mm}
\draw (0,-1cm) -- (1,-1cm);
\node at (6,-1cm) {The current value is \the\pgflinewidth. \defvalue};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I don't understand how it could tell me the default PGF line width?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I've updated my answer showing one possibility.

Comment: Your method gives seven different values, and I still don't know why the default line width would be any of these.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that you had updated your answer. I guess it is the `\the` command that makes the wonder here. I found [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command) about the command here; it seems to be the key to what I was trying to do before. I guess what it does, in short, is to extracts the value of what comes next, expressed as a physical or unitless quantity? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Yes; `\the` applied to a length expands to the length value (with the unit given in `pt`).

Answer (score 23):

If you mean the standard line width, it's `0.4 pt` or the setting `thin`.

```
\tikzstyle{ultra thin}=              [line width=0.1pt]
\tikzstyle{very thin}=               [line width=0.2pt]
\tikzstyle{thin}=                    [line width=0.4pt]
\tikzstyle{semithick}=               [line width=0.6pt]
\tikzstyle{thick}=                   [line width=0.8pt]
\tikzstyle{very thick}=              [line width=1.2pt]
\tikzstyle{ultra thick}=             [line width=1.6pt]
```

Comment: That might be correct, but do you have any source for that? It would also feel better if I could extract it during compilation somehow and not having to trust information from the web.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Why do you ask online then? (search `tikz.code.tex` for these settings)

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: You can read the manual first. `pgfmanual` will tell you the values.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: as @LeoLiu suggested, by looking in the manual for `line width` you would have found `15.3.1 Graphic Parameters: Line Width, Line Cap, and Line Join` (pgfmanual version October 25, 2010).

Comment: @percusse, @Leo, @Claudio: Thanks. Chapter `15.3.1` did contain the information (and the source) I was looking for, which of course told me what percusse had already said. I has been searching for `pgflinewidth` and thought that would give me the answer I wanted.

Comment: @percusse, @Leo, @Claudio: I was also already a bit sceptical because I had tried to google the default PGF linewidth and I had found answers like `1pt` (which on the other hand didn't make any sense to me because it looked terrible when I was trying to use it).

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever As pgfmanual says (p.156, pgfmanual v2.10): "`line width` (no default, initially 0.4pt)"

Comment: @PolGab: Yes, you're right, it should be "initial value". I just stated my question as asking for the "default PGF line width" and felt I couldn't abruptly switch to "initial value", so I stuck to that for a while.