# What's the unit line width in mm

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say below simple example:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0.5) -- (3mm,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's the line width (default value is 1) in mm should be?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65784/how-can-i-know-the-default-pgf-line-width is probably a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default line width is 0.4pt. 1pt is 1/72.27in. 1in is 25.4mm. ([What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm)).

So the default line width in TikZ is 0.14mm.