# How do I change subsection labeling?

Tags: sectioning

The following code produces 1 next to Foo and 1.1 next to Bar.

```
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
```

How do I produce 1 next to Foo and 1a next to Bar? And 1b for the next subsection, and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the number printing mechanism for `\subsection`. Easiest is to use:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\alph{subsection}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\alph{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! Why is it `\thesubsection` and `\thesection` though? Why prefix it with `the`?

Comment: @DavidFaux: See [The `\the` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764) `\thesection` refers to the printing of the `section` counter, which is internally represented in a different way to what you see. The default is `\arabic{<counter>}`.