# Command to return both font size class and font size in pt

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, lengths, class-options

I am looking for a command to return both the font size class and the font size in pt.

The following approach from @Alan Munn as per this [SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc?newreg=527828a2f0354ee2b08740a7b504bb08) prints font-size values for all standard classes:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thefontsize\LARGE
\end{document}

The current font size is: 17.28pt
```

I would like to twist the output such that it also prints the label of the font-size class

```
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 FONTSIZECLASS is printed as \f@size pt \par}}
```

e.g. for `\LARGE`

```
LARGE is printed as 17.28pt
```

If not feasible, maybe one could twist this [SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125173/how-could-i-check-what-font-size-is-in-pt-for-section-subsection-and-subsub) that prints `The current font size is: XXpt` to include  chapter/section/subsection in the print-out, i.e. `The section font size is: 17.28pt`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize{The HEADING font size is: \f@size pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{\thefontsize}
\section{\thefontsize}
...
\end{document}
```

### Solution presented by @Peter Wilson: Extended MWE for future reference

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\getfontsizeofheading{The current font size is: \f@size pt}
% print given font size in point and in its "font size" (i.e. larger or smaller)
\newcommand\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass[1]{{\string #1 is printed as #1 \f@size pt\par}}
% print the entire string in the size of the fontsize (i.e. larger or smaller)
\newcommand\printfontsizeforfontsizeclass[1]{{#1 \string #1 is printed in \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\tiny}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\scriptsize}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\footnotesize}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\small}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\normalsize}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\large}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\Large}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\LARGE}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\huge}
\getfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\Huge}

\printfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\tiny}
\printfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\scriptsize}
\printfontsizeforfontsizeclass{\footnotesize}
...
\end{document}
```

...which results in (for *printfontsizeforfontsizeclass*)
[image: printfontsizeforfontsizeclass]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will lead you to what you are after.

```
% fontdataprob.tex SE 552560

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thisfontsize}[1]{{#1 The \string #1'' font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\newcommand{\printfontsize}[1]{{The \string #1'' font size is: #1 \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thisfontsize{\LARGE}

\thisfontsize{\tiny}

\printfontsize{\LARGE}

\printfontsize{\tiny}
\end{document}
```

I showed two methods of printing out the font size. Hopefully one will be OK for you.

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevancy, but ... Peter, are you there? Your herries.press email started bouncing a couple hours ago ("user unknown") and I don't know any alternative. Help?!

Comment: @PeterWilson: Thank you so much! `\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{\string #1 is printed as #1 \f@size pt\par}}` - this works like charm!!

Comment: @Peter Wilson: I would love to give you a thumbs up for your answer, but with my 13 points I am not permitted yet (needs 15 at least to caste a vote)

Answer (score 1):

The `fontsize` package provides the `\printsamples` command to print a sample text for all (or some of) the sizing commands provided by the package. With `\sampletext{}` it is possible to print only the value of the font size and the line spacing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% A smoothly scalable font is required for some features:
%\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \sampletext{}

\begin{document}
 
\printsamples{12.4pt}{10.5pt}[footnotesize,footnotesizer,footnotesizerr,footnotesizerrr,small,smallr,smallrr,smallrrr,normalsize,normalsizer,normalsizerr,normalsizerrr]

\printsamples{10.2pt}{8.7pt}[footnotesize,footnotesizer,footnotesizerr,footnotesizerrr,small,smallr,smallrr,smallrrr,normalsize,normalsizer,normalsizerr,normalsizerrr]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard class (no `titlesec` package), you can access the font used for headings with some nasty tricks.

The code below is not optimized and could be better, but it's easier to say in the document `\meaning\section` and look at the final part.

One can devise similar tricks for `\chapter` and `\part`, but they're more complex.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getsectionfont}[1]{% #1 = sectional level
  \edef\section@font{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@seventhofseven#1}}%
  \begingroup\section@font\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\section@size{\f@size}}\x
  \texttt{\string#1}: \texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{\section@font}}
  (\section@size pt)%
}
\newcommand\@seventhofseven[7]{#7}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\getsectionfont{\section}

\getsectionfont{\subsection}

\getsectionfont{\subsubsection}

\getsectionfont{\paragraph}

\getsectionfont{\subparagraph}

\bigskip

\texttt{\meaning\section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @greg: thanks a lot for your proposal. I use the `getsectionfont`-code in an Rmd document knitted with `knitr`. For this, I included the`newcommand` definition in a Tex-template sourced by the file. Unfortunately, I receive the following error when copy & pasting your code `! Argument of \@seventhofseven has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.478 getsectionfont{\section}`

Comment: @mavericks That probably depend on *where* you place the command.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Placed `\makeatletter COMMAND-DEFINITION \makeatother` into the `template.tex` just like the solution proposed by @Peter Wilson and then in the Rmd file the code `\getsectionfont{\section} ...`. Anyway, many, many thanks!