# Get \font equivalent of NFSS font

Tags: fonts

How do I generate a command of the form `\font\namefont =`*`something`* so that it matches an NFSS-style font selection?

I was doing something wrong and misdiagnosed the problem I was having as a mismatch between two packages. The first required NFSS-style commands, lines of the form

```
\def \crdfont {\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}
```

In the other a plain TeX-style font command is required, *e.g.*,

```
\font \namefont = cmssbx8
```

In the actual case I had, `\def\namefont{\crdfont}` actually worked fine (the error came from leaving off the brackets), but it got me thinking: What is the general form of translating NFSS-style selection to plain TeX style?

Is it generally the case that `\font \namefont =`*`identifier`* is interchangeable with `\def\namefont{`*`NFSS commands`*`}`?

Comment: why does gchords require a primitive font command? what fails if you use a LaTeX font declaration?

Comment: `\renewcommand\namefont{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontsize{8}{8}\bfseries}` does the same, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four ways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gtrcrd}
\renewcommand\crdfont{\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{gchords}

% LaTeX savvy way
\begingroup\makeatletter\crdfont\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\DeclareFixedFont\noexpand\namefont
    {\f@encoding}{\f@family}{\f@series}{\f@shape}{\f@size}}\x

% Hackish way (quite similar to how \DeclareFixedFont works
\begingroup\crdfont
\global\font\namefont=\fontname\font
\endgroup

% More hackish way without \global (which can be useful
% if you want to make this definition of \namefont only
% local)
\begingroup\crdfont\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\let\expandafter\namefont\the\font

% Even more hackish way without \global and \expandafter
\begingroup\crdfont\edef\x{\endgroup
  \let\namefont=\the\font}\x % \namefont is already unexpandable

\begin{document}

\A[sus2] Fooo
\chord{t}{x,o,p2,p2,o,o}{Asus2}

\end{document}
```

In all four cases, `\show\namefont` answers with

```
\namefont=select font cmssbx10 at 8.0pt
```

But the simplest way seems to be just

```
\let\namefont\crdfont
```

or, if you want to be respectful of LaTeX conventions,

```
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\crdfont}
```

---

Are the last ways equivalent to the `\DeclareFixedFont` way (or the hackish simplified form)? Not really.

If all the `gchords` package does with `\namefont` is using the command to select a font, there should be no difference. But if `\namefont` is used to extract information from the font with low level commands such as

```
\dimen0=\fontdimen2\namefont
```

for storing in `\dimen0` the em value for the font, then the `\renewcommand` (or `\let`) ways will fail miserably.

Since the only place in `gchords.sty` where `\namefont` appears, apart from where it is defined with `\font`, is

```
\put(\xoff,0){\hbox to \truewidth\ascale{\hss\namefont #3\hss}}
```

(on line 159), the `\renewcommand` or `\let` ways should suffice.

---

TeXnical note. Any font choice in LaTeX ultimately reduces to issuing `\somefont`, after that LaTeX has assigned a meaning to `\somefont` with a declaration that ultimately reduced to

```
\global\font\somefont=foo
```

and `foo.tfm` exists on the system. For example, `\normalfont` ends up with issuing `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` (say we are in the default situation, within a 10pt document) and the instruction

```
\global\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/10=cmr10
```

has been performed in advance. Actually a command named `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` wouldn't be legal in that context, so the real instruction was

```
\global\expandafter\font\csname OT1/cmr/m/n/10\endcsname=cmr10
```

but this is mostly irrelevant. LaTeX font assignment are always global.

There are two ways to access an already defined font; if we have issued `\font\somefont=foo`, then the expansion of

```
\the\somefont
```

is a control sequence equivalent to the command that chooses the external font `foo.tfm`, in this case exactly `\somefont`. One might ask *why* doing this and indeed this would be useless. But after `\the` we can use `\font` and, in this case, a control sequence name equivalent to choosing the *current* font will be generated. See [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command)

So, for instance, if one starts an interactive session in LaTeX and issues

```
\documentclass{article}
\edef\whatsthecurrentfont{\the\font}
\show\whatsthecurrentfont
```

the answer would be

```
> \whatsthecurrentfont=macro:
->\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
```

Similarly,

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\whateverthecurrentfontis\expandafter=\the\font
```

would make `\whateverthecurrentfontis` a command to set the font that is current at the moment the instruction is performed.

There is another, less known, instruction. If `\somefont` is a font identifier defined with `\font` as above, then the expansion of

```
\fontname\somefont
```

is a string corresponding to the external font name `\somefont` refers to. As before, the special identifier `\font` can be used after `\fontname` and it again refers to the current font.

This should explain the three hackish ways above.

Let's look at the LaTeX savvy way. We can use the `\DeclareFixedFont` high level instruction that ultimately performs a `\font\somefont=foo` type instruction, but uses the NFSS interface.

When `\selectfont` is issued, maybe as part of the working of commands such as `\bfseries`, LaTeX updates the meaning of some control sequences, namely

```
\f@encoding
\f@family
\f@series
\f@shape
\f@size
\f@baselineskip
```

So, if we want to define a control sequence that chooses the current font independently of the context, we can use `\DeclareFixedFont` by using those commands. With the common `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup...}\x` trick we are able to access at the current meaning of those commands, freezing it because we use their expansion. After `\begingroup`, for this particular case, we issue `\makeatletter` for being able to use `\f@...` and `\cdrfont` for selecting the desired font.

Answer (score 2):

```
\DeclareFixedFont\namefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}{10}
```

probably works

You can of course replace say `OT1` by `\encodingdefault`  and `cmss` by `\sfdefault` if you want the declaration to adapt to other settings.