# Change \the\year

Tags: datetime, primitives

Is it possible to make LaTeX believe that the current year is 2012, so that `\the\year` prints 2012?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  % What to do so that the following prints 2012?
  \the\year
\end{document}
```

I haven't found advice in [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/8057); trying to set `\year` using `\setcounter{year}{2012}` didn't work either.

Comment: It's an internal variable, not a LaTeX counter: `\year=2012`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for enlightening me, works like a charm but has to come after `\begin{document}` (not a problem for me). Care to write this as an answer? How does this fit the accepted answer of the linked question?

Comment: I have supplemented my answer there with these parameters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TeX initializes `\day`, `\month`, `\year` and `\time` at the beginning of a job; they are internal integer registers that can be assigned new values. However, there is no LaTeX interface for modifying their values, so the primitive TeX assignment style has to be used: thus

```
\year=2012
```

will do, and similarly for the other registers mentioned above. Leave a space (or end of line) after the value, or append `\relax` to be sure.

Note that `\time` is initialized with the number of minutes past midnight when the job started. The initial values of `\day`, `\month` and `\year` are the expected ones.

You can *print* their values by prefixing the register's name with `\the`, as described in [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/8057).

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, a quick LaTeX interface to the year:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\c@year\year
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\theyear}{\Roman{year}}

\setcounter{year}{2012}

\begin{document}
\theyear
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, without a TeX primitive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\begin{document}
\ThisYear{1492}      Christopher Columbus discovers America in \the\year. \par
\AdvYear{509}        {\em\the\year: A Space Odyssey} was a film made in% 
\AdvYear{-33}        \the\year. \par 
\SetDate[20/07/1969] Man takes first steps on the Moon in \today. \par
\AdvanceDate[16403]  But today is \today.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. So, the `advdate` package interacts with the TeX variables?

Comment: @krlmlr Yes. Commands as `\ThisYear` are fairly simple (only do `\year#1 \relax`) but the package is justified because add x days to `\today` and  obtain the right date is not so easy.