# Save length with \let command

Tags: lengths

I want to save `\fboxsep` length in `\oldfboxsep` and use it later. The following code doesn't work:

```
\newlength{\oldfboxsep}
\let\oldfboxsep\fboxsep % 3pt by default
\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\oldfboxsep}
  Text\fbox{Box}Text
\end{minipage}}
```

While the following code works:

```
\newlength{\oldfboxsep}
\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep} % 3pt by default
\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\oldfboxsep}
  Text\fbox{Box}Text
\end{minipage}}
```

What are the differences between these two ways?

Comment: `\let` is used for command (macro) definitions only, not lengths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `\let` a length/dimension to another, the newly let length points to the same register. In similar respects one might think of this `\let`ting as making a pointer (in programming language) to an existing data structure. For example, consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\let\oldfboxsep\fboxsep % 3pt by default
\show\fboxsep
\show\oldfboxsep

\verb|\fboxsep|: \the\fboxsep\par
\verb|\oldfboxsep|: \the\oldfboxsep

\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}

\verb|\fboxsep|: \the\fboxsep\par
\verb|\oldfboxsep|: \the\oldfboxsep

\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{15pt}

\verb|\fboxsep|: \the\fboxsep\par
\verb|\oldfboxsep|: \the\oldfboxsep

\end{document}
```

To be more specific, the `\show` commands add the following to the `.log`:

```
> \fboxsep=\dimen36.
l.5 \show\fboxsep


> \oldfboxsep=\dimen36.
l.6 \show\oldfboxsep
```

Of course, the proper way is to define a new length and setting the one length to the other, as you did in your second example.

<sub>Perhaps, in a very likewise manner (from the TeX Book):</sub>

> <sub>Is there a significant difference between `\let\a=\b` and `\def\a{\b}`?</sub>
>
> <sub>Yes indeed. In the first case, `\a` receives the meaning of `\b`
>   that is current at the time of the `\let`. In the second case, `\a` becomes
>   a macro that will expand into the token `\b` whenever `\a` is used,
>   so it has the meaning of `\b` that is current at the time of use.
>   You need `\let`, if you want to interchange the meanings of `\a` and `\b`.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

You want to save the *value* of `\fboxsep` and not its meaning. If you

```
\show\fboxsep
```

the answer will be

```
\fboxsep=\dimen36
```

In particular, `\fboxsep` is not a macro, so doing `\let\foo\fboxsep` will simply define `\foo` to be the same as `\dimen36`.

You can still do without defining a new length, by using the mighty `\the` (see [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command)):

```
\edef\savedfboxsep{\the\fboxsep} % 3pt by default
\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\savedfboxsep}
  Text\fbox{Box}Text
\end{minipage}}
```

When the inner `\setlength` instruction is performed, TeX will translate it into

```
\fboxsep=\savedfboxsep\relax
```

and it will expand `\savedfboxsep` because after `=` TeX is looking for a  specification.

---

A possibly better way for realizing the same construction is using a box:

```
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\newenvironment{framedminipage}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}\begin{minipage}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}%
   \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}}
```

The setting of `\fboxsep` to `8pt` will be undone as soon as the `framedminipage` environment ends; it doesn't influence any `\fbox` command inside the environment, because that text has already been typeset.

Note that, since the `\begin` part ends with `\begin{minipage}`, you can (and should) specify the same arguments as if it were `minipage`, including optional ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\newenvironment{framedminipage}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}\begin{minipage}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}%
   \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\medskip

\begin{framedminipage}{.9\textwidth}
  Text\fbox{Box}Text
\end{framedminipage}

\medskip

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]