# Assigning Theorem number from ref

Tags: theorems

I would like to know if there is an easy way to the following.

I have a statement in later part of an article, say `Theorem G` with `\label{Thm:G}`. In the introduction I would like to state this theorem as

**Theorem G**
2 + 2 = 4.

Is this possible?

I would like to have **Theorem 2.1** in the Intro section.

```
%---- MWE
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}  
\section{Intro}

\section{body} 
\begin{thm}\label{theorem G}
$2+2 = 4$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest i don't understand the question's purpose, but the answers below show us a point of view completely different.

Comment: @skpblack: The answer by Werner is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick-and-easy way of obtaining this is to create a mock "duplicate" theorem environment which you never really use in its entirety. Instead, you adjust the counter representation to adopt that of a reference to the theorem you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{thmB}{Theorem}% Dummy theorem

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\renewcommand{\thethmB}{\ref{thm:G}}
\begin{thmB}
$2+2 = 4$.
\end{thmB}

\section{body}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:G}
$2+2 = 4$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The advantage here is that you could use multiple different references throughout your document, merely changing `\thethmB` to your liking.

Comment: Werner: I have one question. I was not able to understand the renewcommand. What does "\thmthmb" do?

Comment: @Youngsu: When you create `\newtheorem{thmB}{Theorem}`, it creates a counter `thmB`. `\thethmB` is the printing mechanism for this counter, which defaults to `\arabic{thmB}` (note that this use of `\the` is different from what is described in [The `\the` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764)). So, `\thethmB` is used or equivalent to **<num>** when printing **Theorem <num>**. All I've done is replaced the usual `\arabic{thmB}` with a reference.