# How to view the result of \showthe\abovedisplayskip in TeXnic Center?

Tags: spacing, equations

How is it possible to view the value of

```
\showthe\abovedisplayskip
```

in TeXnic Center + MikTex 2.9 + Windows 7?

I tried writing the command in a document (type article) and view the result as pdf is generated but was not successful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to look at the console output or in the log-file.

Comment: You can display it in print with `\texttt{\the\abovedisplayskip}` (LaTeX) or `{\tt\the\abovedisplayskip}` (plain TeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\showthe` works exactly like `\the` (see [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command)), with the difference that TeX stops compilation for showing the resulting token list, instead of delivering it to the input stream. So

```
\showthe\abovedisplayskip
```

would interrupt the TeX run (if found in an interactive session) printing

```
> 12.0pt plus 3.0pt minus 9.0pt.
l.10 \showthe\abovedisplayskip
```

(where 10 is a fictitious line number). In case the session is not interactive, you'll find the same information in the log file. Note that most TeX front-ends use noninteractive mode, when launching TeX.

You can see the value without stopping an interactive session or looking for it in the log file by using `\the`:

```
\texttt{\the\abovedisplayskip}
```

(LaTeX) or

```
{\tt\the\abovedisplayskip}
```

(plain TeX) will show the tokens delivered by `\the` in the PDF file.