# How do I expandably extract the length of a box

Tags: expansion

I thought that the construction `\wd\bopxcontrolsequence` was expandable.  But in mucking around in things, it seems not to be.  At least in the following, the code demonstrates that `\wd\aetmpbox` never gets fully expanded in the definition of `\aewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newsavebox\aetmpbox
\begin{document}

\def\aewidth{0pt}%%
\foreach \myitem in {first,a,a bit longer,shorter,very very very very very long}
{\savebox\aetmpbox{\myitem}%%
 \ifdim\wd\aetmpbox>\aewidth\relax
    \xdef\aewidth{\wd\aetmpbox}%%
    \typeout{---> \detokenize\expandafter{\aewidth} :L: \myitem }%%
  \else 
    \typeout{---> \detokenize\expandafter{\aewidth} :s: \myitem }%%
  \fi
}

hello

\end{document}
```

What I did not want to have to create a new length (for whatever reason).  I just wanted to get the value for the width of my box to be saved in the macro `\aewidth` for later use.

Comment: `\xdef\aewidth{\the\wd\aetmpbox}` perhaps? If I apply this way, I can use `\aewidth` in `\setlength` ....

Comment: You have to build the box anyway, so it can't be fully expandable.

Comment: @egreg I thought `\savebox\aetmpbox{\myitem}` was building the box.

Comment: `\xdef\aewidth{\the\wd\aetmpbox}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\wd` is an unexpandable primitive; `\aetempbox` is a *chardef token*, so it's unexpandable. Hence

```
\xdef\aewidth{\wd\aetmpbox}
```

is exactly the same as `\def\aewidth{\wd\aetmpbox}`

However, `\the` is expandable!

```
\xdef\aewidth{\the\wd\aetmpbox}
```

See [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command)