# Using custom counter in section titles

Tags: counters

I am trying to use custom counters in the titles of several sections, but I am not talking about the numbering system Latex uses for sections, that's ok. I just want to use a counter in the title.

Better explained with an example:

```
2.1.2. Title 1
2.1.3. Title 2
2.1.4. Title 3
```

I just want those `1`, `2` and `3` after `Title` to be a variable I can increment. I have tried using `\newcounter` and `\stepcounter` but I must have been using them wrong because they did nothing.

This is what I tried:

```
\newcounter{ntitle}
\subsection{Title \value{ntitle}}

\stepcounter{ntitle}
...
```

Comment: Can you show what you did?

Comment: @Werner Sure. Check the update.

Comment: `\thentitle` not `\value{ntitle}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\value{<cntr>}` is an internal presentation of a counter and typically used in calculations, not presentation. For that, you may want to use `\the<cntr>` or redefine `\the<cntr>` to suit your needs (using `\alph`, `\Alph`, `\roman`, `\Roman`, ...).

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{ntitle}% Counter
\renewcommand{\thentitle}{\alph{ntitle}}% Counter representation

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{ntitle}{3}% Start value

\section{Title \thentitle}

\stepcounter{ntitle}% Next value

\section{Title \thentitle}

\stepcounter{ntitle}% Next value

\section{Title \thentitle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you refer to the docs please? I couldn't find that.

Comment: @dabadaba https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters

Comment: The [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) [documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) mentions counter representations and `\the<cntr>` in section **21 Counters and Lengths** (p 132). Note that this is slightly different from [The `\the` command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764).