# \refstepcounter does not print the counter

Tags: counters, printing

So I am trying to automate a counter using new counter and `\refstepcounter`. However I would like to print the number of the counter and the code below does not seem to word. Any idea why?

```
\newcounter{taskcounter}
\stepcounter{taskcounter}
\refstepcounter{taskcounter}
```

Comment: These only manipulate a counter macro. You'll need `\thetaskcounter` to print it. Note that stepcounter and refstepcounter both step up the value by one. The ref version just adds extra code such that `\label` can pick up the value.

Answer (score 2):

In order to display the value of a counter `<X>` within your document, use `\the<X>`. For you specific example,

```
\thetaskcounter
```

This defaults to `\arabic{<x>}`, but can be changed.

`\refstepcounter` has nothing to do with the representation of the counter; it steps the counter (like `\stepcounter`) but also updates the components needed for referencing (via `\label`-`\ref`).

Related reference: [The `\the` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/5764)