# An error using \par\xdef\tpd

Tags: tex-core

Why do I get an error message with `\par\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth}` but not with `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}


\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{4.875in}
\noindent \textbf{1. }The following figure depicts three congruent semicircles bounded by another \\
semicircle; the diameters of the three smaller semicircles cover the diameter of \\
the bigger semicircle, and each of the three smaller semicircles is tangent to \\
two other semicircles at the endpoints of its diameter. \textit{A} is the area of the \\
region enclosed by the three smaller semicircles, and \textit{B} is the area of the \par\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{-0.25cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north west)]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill=blue!50] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5) -- cycle;
%
\draw[fill=yellow] (-3/2,0) -- (-1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (-1/2,0) -- (1/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow] (1/2,0) -- (3/2,0) arc (0:180:1/2) -- cycle;

\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\prevdepth=\tpd
enclosed by the big semicircle but outside the three smaller semicircles. Compute the ratio of $A : B$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is `Undefined control sequence.` because you have not defined `\region`.

Comment: Btw: Never end lines/sentences with `\\ `.

Comment: `\the` is a specific command, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/4427 for more information.

Comment: `\end{minipage}
\hspace{-0.25cm}
\raisebox`  makes a space that is -0.25cm less than the width of two interword spaces. If that is what you want then fine, but it seems a strange length to specoify.

Comment: it only makes sense to query `\prevdepth` _after_  a paragraph, and setting it mid-paragraph as you do here does not do anything useful as tex will set it once the paragraph finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You get an error because `\region` is not a defined command.
2. A `minipage` with the `t` option has a very large depth, so the next line will be separated from it with `\lineskip` glue.
3. If instead we measure the depth of the last line in the `minipage`, we can reinsert that depth prior to starting the next paragraph, so ensuring constant baseline skip.
4. What's `\tpd`? Just a temporary macro. You could call it `\depthofthelastlineintheminipage` or whatever name you like, so long as it's not likely to be a used command.
5. Why `\xdef`? Because `minipage` forms a group and a simple `\def` would not make the macro survive the end of the group.
6. Why `\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}`? Because we want to use the actual value of `\prevdepth` at the moment the definition is made; `\xdef` is the same as `\global\edef` and so `\the` will be expanded. See [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/4427) for more information on `\the`.

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined the macro `\region` in your document and it is not provided by any of the included packages.  The `\xdef` definition

```
\xdef\tpd{\region\prevdepth}
```

forces full expansion of its replacement text for which the definition of `\region` is needed.  If `\region` is undefined at that point you will get an error `! Undefined control sequence.`.  This is in contrast to a regular `\def` definition like

```
\def\tpd{\region\prevdepth}
```

where the definition of the tokens in the replacement text only has to known when `\tpd` is actually expanded.

Read chapter 20 “Definition (also called Macros)” in the TeXbook for more details.