# Get correct results for overwritten font identifier

Tags: fonts, tex-core, primitives

How can I get a correct font identifier with `\showthe` and `\the` after it is overwritten? The MWE is below (Same result with all of Knuth TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, (e-)pTeX, (e-)upTeX and Aleph. Only LuaTeX behaves differently, which returns `\X` for all tests.)

```
%#!plain TeX
\font\X=ec-lmr10\X % set \X to the current font
\font\Y=ec-lmr10   % same as current font
\showthe\font % > \Y (most recently defined CS that selects the same font)
\showthe\X    % > \Y (same as above)
\font\Y=cmbx10
\showthe\font % > \Y (!!!)
\showthe\X    % > \Y (!!!)
\end
```

The TeXbook says

> `\the`⟨*font*⟩ produces a font identifier that selects the specified font. For example, ‘`\the\font`’ is a control sequence corresponding to the current font.

The free book *TeX for the Impatient* explains the behavior in more detail (as mentioned in [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command/38676#38676))

> `\the`⟨*font*⟩, which expands to the most recently defined control sequence
>   that selects the same font as the control sequence ⟨*font*⟩

However, both of them fails to explain the behavior as noted with `(!!!)`.

Comment: LuaTeX would show the same behavior if `luaotfload.sty` were loaded (which is the default in LuaLaTeX). The observed difference occurs because LuaTeX will load the same font multiple times by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at modules 548,222, 233, 234 of `tex.web`.

The output of `\showthe\X` in the last case is shown as `\Y`, but this is a “frozen” version of `\Y`, that has no relation with the current meaning `\Y` might have.

The same font (precisely, `tfm` file) can be associated to a control sequence any number of times, but the font will only be loaded once. The font number (*font_id_base*) points to the (frozen) control sequence that selects the same font assigned *last*. There is no way to recover the control sequence name the font was associated to first.

If I try

```
\font\X=ec-lmr10 \X % set \X to the current font
\font\Y=ec-lmr10    % same as current font

Non bold

\tenbf Bold text % to ensure we have changed the current font

\def\Y{Whatever} \Y % redefine \Y

\edef\test{\the\X} {\tt\meaning\test} % it shows macro:->\Y

\test Non bold % however it chooses the expected font

\end
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this investigation! This is... disturbing. So, one can't trust `\show` or `\meaning` to tell precisely what's in a macro. If I insert `\def\foo{\Y}
\show\test
\show\foo
\ifx\foo\test same\else different\fi` in your example after your comment `it shows macro:->\Y`, the two `\show` commands can make us believe that `\test` and `\foo` have the same meaning, but as the `\ifx` and the end of your example demonstrate, they don't!

Comment: @frougon Yes, if I add `\def\testb{\Y}` and do `\ifx\test\testb` I get false. Font memory management had been a big problem and Knuth did many optimizations around it. This is one.