# exam: Macros for printing the values of \labelwidth and \labelsep for question/part

Tags: macros, exam, lengths

How can I print the values of `\labelwidth`/`\labelsep` for both questions and parts?

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{8mm}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}%
    \def\makelabel##1{##1}%
}

\begin{document}
    The length of question \verb|\labelwidth| is ??? and its \verb|\labelsep| is ???, while the length of part \verb|\labelwidth| is ??? and its \verb|\labelsep| is ???.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the magic `\the`: `\the\labelwidth`, `\the\labelsep`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik How to differentiate between that of question and the other of part?

Comment: You cannot, unless you use different names for them. Once you execute `\questionshook`, `\labelwidth` will be `-\labelsep` (whatever value the latter may have), and after you execute `\partshook`, `\labelwidth` will be `8mm`. It can't be both at the same time. You can, of course, save those values in a different register, say, `\partlabelwidth` and `\questionlabelwidth`, and then use these in the document.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I would be grateful if you could edit my MWE to show me how to preserve and print the values of both length registers without overwriting each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have one length register hold two different values. Once you execute `\questionshook`, `\labelwidth` will be `-\labelsep` (whatever value the latter may have), and after you execute `\partshook`, `\labelwidth` will be `8mm`. It can't be both at the same time.

What you can do, is save those values in a different register, say, `\partlabelwidth` and `\questionlabelwidth`, and then use these names in the document.

In the MWE below I defined four new length registers, `\partlabelsep`, `\partlabelwidth`, `\questionlabelsep`, and `\questionlabelwidth`. Then, inside a group, I used `\partshook` to make the part values active, and then copied them to the new registers using `\global\setcounter`, and then the same to `\questionshook`. Beware that some values are not initialised in `\questionshook`, so the order here matters!

When you have those values, you can use [the mighty `\the`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38680/134574) to print their value:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{8mm}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}%
    \def\makelabel##1{##1}%
}
\newlength{\partlabelsep}
\newlength{\partlabelwidth}
\newlength{\questionlabelsep}
\newlength{\questionlabelwidth}
\begingroup
  \partshook
  \global\setlength{\partlabelsep}{\labelsep}
  \global\setlength{\partlabelwidth}{\labelwidth}
  \questionshook
  \global\setlength{\questionlabelsep}{\labelsep}
  \global\setlength{\questionlabelwidth}{\labelwidth}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
    The length of question \verb|\labelwidth| is \the\questionlabelwidth\ and its \verb|\labelsep| is \the\questionlabelsep,
    while the length of part \verb|\labelwidth| is \the\partlabelwidth\ and its \verb|\labelsep| is \the\partlabelsep.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Diaa Yes, the way they are defined there they just change the value of some registers. About converting units, there's [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/134574), with a few nice answers. If you don't mind loading `expl3` then you can use `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{3.1415pt}{1mm}`. If neither of these is good for you, you can define `\def\convertunit#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr1pt*\number\dimexpr(#1)\relax/\number\dimexpr(1#2)\relax\relax\ #2}`, and then `\convertunit{3.1415pt}{mm}`. `\convertunit{\labelsep}{mm}` will also work.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I deleted my original comment after I found some relevant questions, however, your comment is equally helpful.

Comment: @Diaa No worries. Glad it helped :-)