# Use a LaTeX length for an arrow head length in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, lengths

I draw an arrow in Tikz and I want to specify the length with a LaTeX length, e.g., `\headlength`, instead of explicitly writing the length, e.g., `2em`. However, it seems that the TikZ does not like LaTeX lengths as input for the length of the arrow head. (See example below)

How could I give a LaTeX length to the option `length=`? (Thanks!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Latex[length=2em]}] (0,0) -- (2,0); %It works!
\newlength{\headlength}
\setlength{\headlength}{2em}
\draw[-{Latex[length=\headlength]}] (0,1) -- (2,1); %It outputs error
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\the\headlength`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newlength{\headlength}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\headlength}{2em}
\draw[-{Latex[length=2em]}] (0,0) -- (2,0); %It works!
\draw[-{Latex[length=\the\headlength]}] (0,1) -- (2,1); %Works as well
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Allocate registers in the preamble, not inside the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where to look in the manual for "\the"? (my viewer(mac preview) refuses to search for "\the")

Comment: @hpekristiansen See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/4427

Comment: Great. very handy solution. Now I understand that TikZ does not takes LaTeX lengths (registers) in the option `length`, but just "text".

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick fix via `math` library (I am not satisfied: it looks like a patch and I do not understand why it works)

Just store the LaTeX length in a `tikzmath` variable and voilà.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\headlength}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Latex[length=2em]}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\setlength{\headlength}{2em}
\tikzmath{ %
\mylength=\headlength; %Storing the length in a tikzmath variable
}
\draw[-{Latex[length=\mylength]},red] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]