# How to get (measure) the height or the width of an object?

Tags: dimensions, measure

If I want to specify the dimension of some object like `rule{<width>}{<height>}`, such that these dimensions are those of other objects, then how can I get (measure) the height and width of these other object and pass them to the arguments of `rule{<width>}{<height>}`. I'm looking for sth that takes a suitable object `Object` and gives one of its dimensions like `h = \height{Object_1}` , or like `w = \height{Object_2}` .

**The main issue is *getting* the dimensions of given objects, *not using* the `rule`**

Comment: `\begingroup \setbox0=\hbox{...} \message{height: \the\ht0, depth: \the\dp0, width: \the\wd0}\endgroup`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX provides `\settowidth{<len>}{<stuff>}` and `\settoheight{<len>}{<stuff>}` that sets `<len>` to either the width or the height of `<stuff>`. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylen}

abc has width 
\settowidth{\mylen}{abc}\the\mylen,
height
\settoheight{\mylen}{abc}\the\mylen{}
and depth
\settodepth{\mylen}{abc}\the\mylen.

def has width 
\settowidth{\mylen}{def}\the\mylen,
height
\settoheight{\mylen}{def}\the\mylen{}
and depth
\settodepth{\mylen}{def}\the\mylen.

ghi has width 
\settowidth{\mylen}{ghi}\the\mylen,
height
\settoheight{\mylen}{ghi}\the\mylen{}
and depth
\settodepth{\mylen}{ghi}\the\mylen.

\end{document}
```

You can also capture the content in a box and then pull the dimensions from there (width via `\wd<box>`, height via `\ht<box>` and depth via `\dp<box>`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\savebox{\mybox}{abc}%
abc has width \the\wd\mybox,
height \the\ht\mybox{}
and depth \the\dp\mybox.

\savebox{\mybox}{def}%
def has width \the\wd\mybox,
height \the\ht\mybox{}
and depth \the\dp\mybox.

\savebox{\mybox}{ghi}%
ghi has width \the\wd\mybox,
height \the\ht\mybox{}
and depth \the\dp\mybox.

\end{document}
```

`\the` above is just used to print the lengths. See [The `\the` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674).