# Nested Footnotes + Hyperref

Tags: hyperref, numbering, footnotes

Footnoting a footnote can be performed by placing a `\footnotemark` within a footnote, followed later by the accompanying `\footnotetext`. However, only a *single* footnote can be placed within a footnote because of [footnote counter desynchronization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38643/10127). This problem was [solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38652/10127), but the solution turned out to be incompatible with the `\hyperref` package (despite disabling `hyperfootnotes` in the `\usepackage{hyperref}` declaration).

The below MWE demonstrates this incompatibility.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

    % comment the below line to resolve the footnote numbering problem
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

    % solution proposed by Werner (begin)
    \usepackage{letltxmacro}
    \newcounter{fnmarkcntr}\newcounter{fntextcntr}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\footnotemark}{%
       \@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark
         {\stepcounter{fnmarkcntr}%
          \refstepcounter{footnote}\label{footnotemark\thefnmarkcntr}%
          \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
          \@footnotemark}}
    \makeatother
    \LetLtxMacro{\oldfootnotetext}{\footnotetext}
    \renewcommand{\footnotetext}[1]{%
      \stepcounter{fntextcntr}%
      \oldfootnotetext[\ref{footnotemark\thefntextcntr}]{#1}
    }
    % solution proposed by Werner (end)

    \begin{document}
    This text has a footnote\footnote%
    {Which contains a sub-footnote\footnotemark}
    \footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled `2'}
    \end{document}
```

Shown below is the output of the above code with the `\usepackage{hyperref}` command removed.

[image]

Shown below is the **erroneous** output of the above code with the `\usepackage{hyperref}` command included.

[image]

Note that inclusion of the `hyperref` package results in incorrect numbering of the nested footnote (0 instead of 2) and placement of an undesired (albeit correctly numbered) `footnotemark` in the body of the text (it should be placed in the footnote). This undesired `footnotemark` has been erroneously hyperlinked.

Comment: As you chose to accept Werner's answer to the original question and to ask a follow-up question with regard to the `hyperref` incompatibility, it seems appropriate that you move the respective MWE ("Edit 2") to this new question.

Comment: Perhaps also remove the "new" MWE from the original question.

Comment: BTW, your MWE results in an error even if I comment out `hyperref`.

Comment: Yes, that error is because I included a hyperlink (www.google.com), which is no longer recognized if the `hyperref` package is omitted. For simplicity, I will remove that -- it does not add anything substantive to the example.

Comment: @user001: Although it is a good idea to keep your post current and therefore obtain the best possible solution, editing it more than 10 times automatically turns it into a [Community Wiki](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480/what-does-community-wiki-mean) post, removing any reputation gain for you.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, that is not a problem. Since there were no answers, I thought that perhaps the post was lacking in either simplicity, clarity, or both. Hence the constant refinements.

Comment: @user001: I removed the automated CW from the question again.

Comment: @user001 accidently [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57100/5049) to your [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39461/5049) offers a solution...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to (ab)use the [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}[2011/11/26]% v1.0e

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is a footnote\footnote{Here is a footnote within the footnote%
\tablefootnote{This footnote should be labeled `2'}. %
And here is another one\tablefootnote{This footnote should be labelled `3'}.}%
\spewnotes{}. Text\footnote{Another footnote%
\tablefootnote{This footnote should be labelled `5'}. %
And here is another one\tablefootnote{This footnote should be labelled `6'}}\spewnotes{}.

\newpage

Some text (which is necessary to get two pages,
thus one can choose continuous view of the pdf-file and then check
that the hyperreferences indeed aim to the correct point.

\end{document}
```

You just need to make sure that there is no page break between '\footnote{...}' and `\spewnotes`, otherwise the spewed footnotes end at the second page. (And I did not test what happens when you use a table with `tablefootnote` at the same page as your footnotes to footnotes, but one can deal with that problem in the unlikely case that it does really occur.)

Comment: Posting the exact answer twice is discouraged here and will cause the answer to be automatically flagged. Simply adding a comment to the original answer would be better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Sorry, had done that at the time when this was CW and the questions both ask for a solution to the same problem, just this question additionally asks for hyperref, thus the one answer answers both questions. I'll include a comment at the other version of the question linking to this answer. (A bit of a complicated situation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `\ref` in Werner's answer to `\getrefnumber` from the `refcount` package it works with `hyperref` (if `hyperfootnote=false` isn't passed there are warnings about `footnotemark` links that lead to nowhere).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

% modified solution by Werner (begin)
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{fnmarkcntr}\newcounter{fntextcntr}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnotemark}{%
   \@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{fnmarkcntr}%
      \refstepcounter{footnote}\label{footnotemark\thefnmarkcntr}%
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
      \@footnotemark}}
\makeatother
\LetLtxMacro{\oldfootnotetext}{\footnotetext}
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{fntextcntr}%
  \oldfootnotetext[\getrefnumber{footnotemark\thefntextcntr}]{#1}
}
% modified solution by Werner (end)

\begin{document}
This text has a footnote\footnote%
{Which contains a sub-footnote\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{This footnote should be labeled `2'}
\end{document}
```