# \footnotes in environment with \pushftn \popftn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, footnotes

[Code proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43695/7128) by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) works out-of-the box, cause has no package dependencies. It's comfortable solution of dealing with footnotes in environments needing `\footnotemark`+`footnotetext`.

I have no problems in using it with `\vbox` and `itemize`.

However when I try to apply it to centred tabular I encounter problem - footnotes are not rendered, only footmarks:

```
\documentclass{report}

%Thanks to David Carlisle for pushftn and popftn : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43695/7128
\makeatletter
\newtoks\FTN@ftn
\def\pushftn{%
 \let\@footnotetext\FTN@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\FTN@xftntext
  \let\@xfootnote\FTN@xfootnote}
\def\popftn{%
 \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\FTN@ftn}
\long\def\FTN@ftntext#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\FTN@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext
                    [\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname]}%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
\long\def\FTN@xftntext[#1]#2{%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\the\FTN@ftn\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}}
\def\FTN@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark\FTN@xftntext[#1]}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pushftn
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
X & Y \\
\hline
\hline
a & b \footnote{AB} \\
\hline
c & d \footnote{CD} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\popftn

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `table` environment builds a box; so `\pushftn` must go inside it. Of course this will fail if the table is typeset as a page float.

Comment: Also you might want to replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you had me confused there for a while.
Stick `\begingroup` before the push and `\endgroup` *before* the pop.

the idea is that you *locally* redefine the footnote commands to save their contents but the code assumes that by the time you execute the saved commands they have their normal meanings back, otherwise they just save their contents again.

Note though that lifting the footnotes out of the floating table is inherently fragile, if the table floats off to another page, the footnotes will not float with it, and if it ends on a `p` float page, LaTeX does not support footnotes on such a page.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works :) `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` solves problem. Your description clarifies me how all this works. Good point of not using `footnotes` inside `floats`, I've forgot about this.