# Footnotes tabularx-environment LaTeX

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

I've been trying to find a satisfying solution to the footnotes-in-tables-problem for hours now. Nothing I come across seems to work the way it should. Still, in the `tabularx` package documentation it is stated that `tabularx` supports `\footnote`.

I've tried using the

```
\footnote{footnote text}
```

command in the `tabularx` environment, and it for sure shows the footnote in the table (hallelujah!), but not the footnote text (not so much hallelujah).

I've also tried

```
\footnotemark[footnote#]
```

with

```
\footnotetext[footnote#]{footnote text}
```

somewhere underneath the table, which works perfectly fine, except that you have to keep track of the counters yourself, which results in tragedy when you insert a normal `\footnote` elsewhere in the text on the page.

The best solution would be if one could have lettered footnotes in the table and numbered for the text, but `\footnotemark` does not support using letters as numbers.

So... does anyone understand how `tabularx` works with footnotes?

A MWE:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Characteristics of the most common reactor types}
\label{tab:reactor-properties}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{*{4}{L}}
\toprule
Type    & Fuel \footnotemark[1] & Moderator  & Coolant  \\
\midrule
LGR \footnotemark[2] & \ce{UO2}, enr. & Graphite, \ce{H2O}  & \ce{H2O}(\emph{l}) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\footnotetext[1]{enr. = enriched in \ce{^{235}U}, nat. = natural}
\footnotetext[2]{There were four such reactors at the Chernobyl plant at the time of the accident \cite{nuclear-energy}}
```

EDIT: The solution offered by David Carisle worked perfectly for a day or so. I have no idea why it stopped working, but both the footnote-text and references have stopped working in a minipage-tabularx-environment. A MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry,parskip,setspace,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,gensymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,booktabs,multirow,url,hyperref}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[ref]{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Footnotes in table
\makeatletter
\newtoks\FTN@ftn
\def\pushftn{%
 \let\@footnotetext\FTN@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\FTN@xftntext
  \let\@xfootnote\FTN@xfootnote}
\def\popftn{%
 \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\FTN@ftn}
\long\def\FTN@ftntext#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\FTN@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext
                    [\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname]}%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
\long\def\FTN@xftntext[#1]#2{%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\the\FTN@ftn\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}}
\def\FTN@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark\FTN@xftntext[#1]}

\makeatother
%End footnotes in table

% ---------- New Commands ----------
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{Characteristics of the most common desalination processes \cite{ref1} \label{tab:desalination-properties}}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l l L L}
\toprule
Property                &   Reverse Osmosis         &   MSF\footnote{For large MSF plants}      &    MED        \\
\midrule
El.\footnote{El. = electrical} energy consumption    [\si{\kilo\watt\per\cubic\metre}]  &   $6.5-12$    & $4-6$ \ref{ref1}      &   $4.5-12.5$  \\
Th.\footnote{Th. = thermal} energy consumption [\si{\kilo\watt\per\cubic\meter}] &              & $55-120$ \ref{ref1}   &               \\
Plant cost              &   High                        &   Medium      &   Low         \\
Product quality         &   Medium\footnote{Energy dependent}   &   High            &   High            \\
Feed pretreatment       &   High                        &   Medium      &   Low         \\
Maintenance             &   High                        &   Low         &   Low         \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ref1} Some reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

As seen in the screen dump below, footnotetext and references (note, I'm importing a bib-file in my document) are not working inside the tabularx-environment:
[image: Table with non-working footnotes and references]

Providing the file list given from \listfiles:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
  latin1.def    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
 siunitx.sty    2012/01/19 v2.4i A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2012/01/19 v3209 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2011/12/30 v3113 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2011/12/29 v3110 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
l3basics.sty    2012/01/15 v3196 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2012/01/15 v3196 L3 Experimental argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental token lists
   l3seq.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2012/01/07 v3139 L3 Experimental integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/01/08 v3148 L3 Experimental quarks
   l3prg.sty    2011/12/31 v3122 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2012/01/09 v3157 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2011/12/31 v3123 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental property lists
   l3msg.sty    2012/01/08 v3153 L3 Experimental messages
    l3io.sty    2012/01/09 v3160 L3 Experimental input-output operations
  l3file.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental file operations
  l3skip.sty    2012/01/07 v3139 L3 Experimental dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2011/12/22 v3086 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2012/01/08 v3154 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
   l3box.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/01/08 v3155 L3 Experimental coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental colour support
l3luatex.sty    2012/01/09 v3158 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2012/01/19 v3207 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2012/01/19 v3209 L3 Experimental document command parser
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
multirow.sty    
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
hyperref.sty    2011/12/04 v6.82m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2011/04/23 v1.4 Subsetting bundle oberdiek (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/04/04 v1.12 Provides string conversions (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Data type bit set (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/01/30 v1.0 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/04/23 v1.7 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2010/12/01 v3.2 Data extraction from references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2011/12/04 v6.82m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2011/12/04 v6.82m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 caption.sty    2011/11/10 v3.2e Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2011/11/01 v1.4a caption3 kernel (AR)
  mhchem.sty    2011/06/03 v3.11 for typesetting chemical formulae
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  twoopt.sty    2008/08/11 v1.5 Definitions with two optional arguments (HO)
appendix.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2b extra appendix facilities
    cite.sty    2010/09/10  v 5.3
fancyhdr.sty    
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2012/01/19 v2.4i siunitx: Abbreviated units
siunitx-binary.cfg    2012/01/19 v2.4i siunitx: Binary units
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
"Test document".out
"Test document".out
    umsa.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Comment: You can just use `\footnotemark` and then `\footnotetext{...}` - you don't have to specify the footnote number. Moreover, `tabularx` saves `\footnotetext` in a token register to be recalled after the environment. A simple example shows that `\footnote`s in `tabularx` works. Would you be able to provide a small example that shows your problem (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Comment: I ran your MWE unchanged and got footnotes see image in my updated answer

Comment: Besides `parnotes`, you may want to look at [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) or [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a good opportunity to pimp out `parnotes`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry,parskip,setspace,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,gensymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,booktabs,multirow,url,hyperref}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[ref]{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}
%
% This will go in the next version
%
\makeatletter
\def\parnoteclear{%
    \gdef\PN@text{}%
    \parnotereset
}
\makeatother

% ---------- New Commands ----------
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Characteristics of the most common desalination processes \cite{ref1} \label{tab:desalination-properties}}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l l L L}
\toprule
\parnoteclear % tabularx will otherwise add each note thrice
Property                &   Reverse Osmosis         &   MSF\parnote{For large MSF plants}      &    MED        \\
\midrule
El.\parnote{El. = electrical} energy consumption    [\si{\kilo\watt\per\cubic\metre}]  &   $6.5-12$    & $4-6$ \ref{ref1}      &   $4.5-12.5$  \\
Th.\parnote{Th. = thermal} energy consumption [\si{\kilo\watt\per\cubic\meter}] &              & $55-120$ \ref{ref1}   &               \\
Plant cost              &   High                        &   Medium      &   Low         \\
Product quality         &   Medium\parnote{Energy dependent}   &   High            &   High            \\
Feed pretreatment       &   High                        &   Medium      &   Low         \\
Maintenance             &   High                        &   Low         &   Low         \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\parnotes
\end{table}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ref1} Some reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Probably *somebody* understands `tabularx`:-)

The footnote in `tabularx` is designed to enable *page* footnotes with the text coming at the end of the page. If you are not seeing the text then most likely you have the table in some other box (such as a float) that inhibits footnotes whether or not they are in a table.

If you want table notes the standard latex way is to put the `tabular` in a `minipage` then the footnotes come at the end of the minipage.

Or you might prefer the code in this answer

[\footnotetext numbering for many \footnotemark - automatic solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/footnotetext-numbering-for-many-footnotemark-automatic-solution/43695#43695)

Your edited MWE works for me giving footnotes:

[image]

the file list shows that your MWE loads 166 files, approximately all of them are *not* needed for this example, so it's too much to ask anyone to debug. I attach my list below. I would start by removing everything you are not using *in that example* the footnote push/pop from the other answer siunits (and all the l3exp code) in fact as far as I can see your MWE *only* uses `tabularx` then most likely you will get footnotes, then just put back the packages you think you need. If the footnotes go, it is a problem with that package.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
  latin1.def    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
geometry.sty    2010/07/13 v5.5 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2010/01/28 v2.1 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
setspace.sty    2000/12/01 6.7 Contributed and Supported LaTeX2e package
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
   babel.sty    2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
 siunitx.sty    2010/07/15 v2.0n A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2010/07/13 v1982 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2010/07/11 v1981 L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitiv
es
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2010/06/07 v1942 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2010/06/10 v1948 L3 Experimental Argument Expansion module
    l3tl.sty    2010/05/22 v1919 L3 Experimental Token Lists
l3intexpr.sty    2010/06/15 v1957 L3 Integer Expressions
 l3quark.sty    2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental Quark Commands
   l3seq.sty    2010/03/29 v1879 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
  l3toks.sty    2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental Token Registers
   l3int.sty    2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental Integer module
   l3prg.sty    2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2010/03/29 v1878 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2010/04/11 v1890 L3 Experimental token investigation and manipu
lation
  l3prop.sty    2010/03/21 v1857 L3 Experimental Property Lists
   l3msg.sty    2010/03/23 v1866 L3 Experimental LaTeX Messages module
    l3io.sty    2010/05/22 v1923 L3 Experimental i/o module
  l3skip.sty    2010/05/25 v1933 L3 Experimental skip registers
   l3box.sty    2010/05/22 v1919 L3 Experimental Box module
l3keyval.sty    2010/04/11 v1890 L3 Experimental keyval processing
  l3keys.sty    2010/05/24 v1931 L3 Experimental key-value support
l3precom.sty    2010/02/09 v1793 L3 Experimental precompilation module
  l3xref.sty    2010/02/09 v1786 L3 Experimental cross referencing
  l3file.sty    2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental file loading
    l3fp.sty    2010/07/08 v1979 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2009/08/24 v1494 Parsing LaTeX3 keyvals as LaTeX2e package opti
ons
  xparse.sty    2010/05/23 v1927 Generic document command parser
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2010/02/14 v0.04n Graphics/color for pdfTeX
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
multirow.sty    
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
hyperref.sty    2010/06/18 v6.81g Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Provides hex, PDF name and string conversions 
(HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
 hycolor.sty    2009/12/12 v1.6 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/12/12 xcolor patch
letltxmacro.sty    2008/06/24 v1.3 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2010/06/18 v6.81g Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2010/03/25 v1.12 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2010/06/18 v6.81g Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2010/03/24 v1.5 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2010/03/16 v1.6 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2009/12/18 v1.1 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
 caption.sty    2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2010/01/14 v3.1m caption3 kernel (AR)
  mhchem.sty    2010/06/16 v3.08 for typesetting chemical formulae
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  twoopt.sty    2008/08/11 v1.5 Definitions with two optional arguments (HO)
appendix.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2b extra appendix facilities
    cite.sty    2009/08/29  v 5.2
fancyhdr.sty    
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2007/09/30 v1.0 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2009/12/18 v1.3 Cleanup title references (HO)
   tab77.out
   tab77.out
    umsa.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

As far as I understand, I'm dependent on the float-environment of `\begin{table}` to get the table-caption (which is a must). 

I may be slow, but would the example you provided in the linked post work in a float environment?

Comment: the float doesn't help get table notes, it just prevents page notes. So yes the explict footnote saving code in the other question would work, or tabularx as in your MWE if you went  `\begin{table}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{tabularx`.... so that the footntes from tabularx come at the end of the minipage, ie just under the tabularx

Comment: Is there any situation your solution _wouldn't_ work? I've added the SIunitX package and now all my table footnotes have disappeared - that is, the footnotes are there but the explaining text is gone. References inside the `tabularx`-environment shows up as ?'s to. Help, please! Report due to tomorrow evening... :p

Comment: Please edit your question to make a complete (small) document that shows the problem, then someone may be able to help

Comment: Edited! This one compiles =)

Comment: Seriously? But how can that be? I thought that it shouldn't matter which compiler one uses? I'm a TeXshopper. I've tried to restart TeXshop, deleting all files but the .tex-file and compile over again, but it just won't do. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: add \listfiles to your document and post the listing it produces into your answer

Comment: Done. Assuming you ment ´\listfiles`in the preamble and the produced listing was from the console...

Comment: I apologize for the long list. I've removed all packages and started from the bottom with compiling and adding the packages that is needed. That produced the table with footnotes! =D The Hyperref-package was the sinner. But as I can see from your screen dump the citations in the tables are still is `??`. Do you understand why? This happens in my main document too, even with the citations located in the footnote text. But only for the tables, though... Of course you're right, citations that is.

Comment: you have `\ref{ref1}` but no `\label{ref1}` perhaps you meant `\cite`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3091/discussion-between-holene-and-david-carlisle)