# A related question on "\footnotetext numbering for many \footnotemark - automatic solution"

Tags: footnotes

David Carslie proposed a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/footnotetext-numbering-for-many-footnotemark-automatic-solution/43695#43695). The question is what to do if you have an environment that is several pages and you want the footnote to appear at the bottom of the page where the footnote mark appear not at the bottom of the last page.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\FTN@ftn
\def\pushftn{%
 \let\@footnotetext\FTN@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\FTN@xftntext
  \let\@xfootnote\FTN@xfootnote}
\def\popftn{%
 \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\FTN@ftn}
\long\def\FTN@ftntext#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\FTN@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext
                    [\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname]}%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
\long\def\FTN@xftntext[#1]#2{%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\the\FTN@ftn\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}}
\def\FTN@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark\FTN@xftntext[#1]}

\makeatother
\usepackage{framed,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}\pushftn
\footnote{Test}\lipsum
\end{framed}\popftn

\end{document}
```