# Footnote in tabu table not shown

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabu

Which package should I use for proper footnote handling in `tabu` tables? I thought `tabu` was supposed to do everything `tabularx` does, but footnotes do not show up in `tabu` tables.

Working (using `tabularx`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{c}
Cell \footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Not working (with `tabu`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{c}
Cell \footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Seems to be a bug as far as I understand `tabu`s documentation. The maintainer is Florent Chervet. Does this package have a bug tracker?

Comment: It works if you load `hyperref` after `tabu` and don't use `tabu` inside `table` as it is a float.

Comment: Or you can use the `threeparttable` (or `threeparttablex`), which I found to be the best option.

Comment: @cacamailg: I thought `tabu` was supposed to be in `table`; `tabu` for example doesn't support `\caption`.

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunately it seems there is a bug. You can use `\captionof` instead of `\caption`. I will try to provide an example.

Comment: I could not find any bug tracker, so I emailed the author, but I didn't receive a reply, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % this line is added.
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{c}
Cell \footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

As @cacamailg said in comment, "It works if you load hyperref after tabu".
Thank you, @cacamailg.

Comment: I added `hyperref` to my document (even if it wasn't used before) but my footnotes still don't show up. Although other footnotes that were already showing up now have a hyperlink as well.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: check this link for comprehensive list of solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex/2891556#2891556

Answer (score 1):

The code below seem to work:

```
\documentclass{report}

%Thanks to David Carlisle for pushftn and popftn : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43695/7128
\makeatletter
\newtoks\FTN@ftn
\def\pushftn{%
 \let\@footnotetext\FTN@ftntext\let\@xfootnotenext\FTN@xftntext
  \let\@xfootnote\FTN@xfootnote}
\def\popftn{%
 \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\FTN@ftn}
\long\def\FTN@ftntext#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\FTN@ftn\noexpand\footnotetext
                    [\the\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname]}%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\@tempa{#1}}}%
\long\def\FTN@xftntext[#1]#2{%
  \global\FTN@ftn\expandafter{\the\FTN@ftn\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}}
\def\FTN@xfootnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
   \endgroup
   \@footnotemark\FTN@xftntext[#1]}

\makeatother

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\caption{Testing table}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace{-0.5\skip\footins}}
%\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\begingroup\pushftn
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{lX}
\toprule
a & b\footnote{AB} \\
\midrule
c & d\footnote{CD} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\endgroup\popftn
\end{varwidth}
\end{table}

\noindent
Some text 1\footnote{This is a footnote 1.}.
\noindent
Some text 2\footnote{This is a footnote 2.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `pushftn` thing not the same as `\begin{savenotes}` provided by the `footnote` package?