# Make eledmac footnotes available in tabular environment

Tags: tables, footnotes, eledmac

Is there a way to make eledmac footnotes available in tabular environments? 
The `\savenotes` and `\makesavenoteenv` commands from footnote.sty don't work here anymore.

In the following MWE, footnotes inside the table just don't appear. The label is set, but not the foornote.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\RequirePackage{eledmac}
\newseries{T}
\let\footnote\footnoteT

\begin{document}
Foo bar\footnote{This footnote works.}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & B \\
    C\footnote{This footnote doesn't appear.} & D \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `eledmac`'s footnote engine for familiar footnotes. (And I cannot switch away from `eledmac`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution now that implements a push pop system, pushing footnotes into a token list within the tabular (and any other) environment and spawning them after the end. The basic idea was inspired from cacamailg's answer in the post: [Footnote in tabu table not shown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110682/footnote-in-tabu-table-not-shown)

My solution provides a `\Mymakesavenoteenv` command which works similar to `\makesavenoteenv` from `footnote.sty`. You can selectively activate the environments you like to be able to handle footnotes. 
The whole thing was implemented for the footnote series `T`. I preferred making this specific to one series only to not disturb the `eledmac` functionality otherwise. (I'm using series `T` for global normal footnotes.)

Here the solution MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

\newseries{T}
\def\footnote#1{\footnoteT{#1}}

% push-pop-system for eledmac footnotes, saving footnotes around an environment. 
\newtoks\Myftn@toks

\newcommand*{\@popftn@vfootnoteT}[3]{%
    \def\@thefnmarkT{#1}%
    \vfootnoteT{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\pushftn{%
    \let\vfootnoteT\@pushftn@vfootnoteT
}

\def\popftn{%
    \global\Myftn@toks\expandafter{\expandafter}\the\Myftn@toks%
}%

\long\def\@pushftn@vfootnoteT#1#2{%
    \edef\@tempa{\the\Myftn@toks\noexpand\@popftn@vfootnoteT
        {\csname @thefnmarkT\endcsname}{T}{#2}}%
    \global\Myftn@toks\expandafter{\@tempa}%
}%

\def\Mymakesavenoteenv#1{
    \AtBeginEnvironment{#1}{\pushftn}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{#1}{\popftn}
}

% push pop functionality can simply be activated for selected environments 
% similar to \makesavenoteenv from footnotes.sty 
\Mymakesavenoteenv{longtable}
\Mymakesavenoteenv{tabular}

\makeatother 

\begin{document}

Foo bar\footnote{This footnote works.}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}l}
    A & B \\
    C\footnote{tabular p-column} & D\footnote{tabular l-column} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}l}
    A & B \\
    C\footnote{longtable p-column} & D\footnote{longtable l-column} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your solution is nice, but quite problematique for longtables: the footnotes will be called only in the final pages.

Comment: I also don't understand why you use eledmac footnote and not normal footnote for your series T.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they only appear at the final page. I Guess I have to engage more with lontable to fix this. But yet, this provies a general solution for many environments (especially tabular!).

Comment: I'm using the excellent `eledmac` footnote system for normal footnotes as I'm actually typesetting twocolumn footnotes in the whole book. And unlike `eledmac`, the classical `dblfnote.sty` solution would not break long footnotes accross pages. This is a tremendous disadvantage in the cases of books I'm doing.

Comment: ok, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Eledmac knows this problem. That's why it provides an edtabularl environnement (§ 13 of the actual handbook).

However, for some technical reason, the `\let\footnote\footnoteC` can't work in this case (see https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/207#issuecomment-54959471 for more details), and you have to do something like `def\footnote#1{\footnoteT{#1}}`.

So the full MWE is :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\RequirePackage{eledmac}
\newseries{T}

\def\footnote#1{\footnoteT{a}}
\begin{document}
Foo bar\footnote{This footnote works.}


\begin{edtabularl}
    A & B \\
    C\footnote{This footnote doesn't appear.} & D \\
\end{edtabularl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the `edtabularl` is not as functional as `tabular`. Especially, I need `p`-columns. And also `longtables`. I will post my solution as a separate answer.

Comment: indeed, it's not as functional. Your solution is welcomed, I could help me to NOT have to implement tabular in eledmac.