# Footnotes not appearing in makecell used in longtable

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, longtable, makecell

I am using a footnote inside makecell inside a longtable and while the footnote's counter is displayed, the text does not appear at the end of the page. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

One & \makecell{abcdef\footnote{Test2} \\ ghjijklmn} & 123.456778 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can verify the problem.

Comment: Replace `\footnote{Test}` with `\footnotemark` and write outside the `longtable` (after \end{longtable}) `\footnotetext{Test}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I considered that but the issue is I need multiple footnotes in the makecell. Multiple footnotemarks/footnotetext does not yield correct numbering for the footnotes.

Comment: Okay, than your question is a duplicate to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43692/124842). So you could use `\footnotemark \footnotemark \footnotemark` and
`\addtocounter{footnote}{-3}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Test 1}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Test 2}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Test 3}`

Comment: The makecell package documentation states that I can use \footnote inside \makecell so there must be something else that is wrong. Also doing it in the way suggested in your comment does not preserve hyperlinks in pdftex.

Comment: @Samidh T: Yes, but maybe not in a `longtable`, which has its own management of `footnotes`. I guess the problem comes from this. Please see my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes  from `\makecell`: it seems that, for some reason, it behaves like the cells before `\endhead` or `\endfoot` in long table. The workaround consists, as explained in the `longtable` documentation, in using `\footnotemark`, and `\footnotetext` in any other ‘normal’ cell that will fall in the same page.

Since you load `makecell`,I took the opportunity to simplify the code for your column heads, using the `\thead` command. I also added some padding for the footnote with the `\gape` command.
    \documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\title{A longtable example}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{12cm}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \thead{First column} & \thead{Second column} & \thead{Third column} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

One & \makecell{abcdef\gape{\footnotemark} \\ ghjijklmn} & \footnotetext{Test2}123.456778 \footnote{Test3} \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to achieve this using the footnotemark/footnotetext combination but this doesn't keep the hyperlinks which footnote does. Also, the solution becomes messy when I need multiple footnotemarks in makecell. I think tabularx might be a better option here.

Comment: If it's a long tabularx, you can try the `ltablex` package.