# Why footnotemark and footnotetext numbering is erroneous?

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I used footnotemark and text in the below document but the footnote numbers below appear erroneously. This occurs even when I run multiple times.   Why this happens? How to correct this?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Ubuntu}

\begin{document}

Let us do \emph{dhyāna}\footnotemark of (Gaṇeśa) the one with white garments, all pervading\footnotemark, of the hue of the moon, with four arms and a pleasing face for him to destroy our impediments.

\footnotetext{pratyayaikatānatā dhyānam -- mind becoming concentrated on one thought / image / icon is called \emph{dhyāna}.}

\footnotetext{vyāpanādviṣṇuḥ = The one who pervades everything. In Sanātana Dharma, Bhagavān pervades all creation. This is in contrast with other religions and schools of thought which hold ``God'' to be some human-like personality sitting somewhere in heaven.}

Having heard the Rāmakathā\footnotemark-roars of the Vālmīki-muni\footnotemark-lion traversing the Kavitā-forest, who indeed would not to achieve the highest abode\footnotemark?

\footnotetext{Rāmakathā = Rāmāyaṇa, the story of Rāma.}

\footnotetext{Muni -- manuta iti muniḥ - the one who is constantly doing \emph{manana} (contemplation) of \emph{śāstras} and \emph{Bhagavān} is a muni.}

\footnotetext{Simple meaning of the \emph{śloka} is that one achieves the highest goal achievable by human i.e. \emph{mokṣa} by learning the Rāmāyaṇa.}


\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output]

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can't "stack" multiple `\footnotemark`s easily, each `\footnotemark` must be discharged with a `\footnotetext` before you can issue a new `\footnotemark`. Work-arounds are surely available, but I'm not sure how automatic they can be - they may require manual intervention. BTW: In this example there is no real reason not to use `\footnote`, but in your actual document the situation might be different and require `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext`. First link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43692/35864

Comment: Is there any compelling reason for using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` rather than `\footnote`?

Comment: Idea was to keep footnotes and main body distinct. As @moewe suggested about work-arounds I used sepfootnotes to handle the situation.