# Labeling a Footnotemark

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, footnotes

Is there a way to label a `\footnotemark` instance (without redefining the `\footnotemark` macro)? Labeling the `\footnotemark` has no effect (it labels whatever environment the command is invoked from) and labeling its corresponding `\footnotetext` is not guaranteed to produce the correct number (it merely returns the current value of the default footnote counter). See below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    This text is footnoted\footnotemark\label{fnm:1} \footnotemark\label{fnm:2}
    \footnotetext{Footnote `1'\label{fnt:1}.}%
    \footnotetext{Footnote `2'\label{fnt:2}.}%

    The numbers of the labels: %
    \{\ref{fnm:1}, \ref{fnt:1}, \ref{fnm:2},  \ref{fnt:2}\}

    The sequence should read: \{1, 1, 2, 2\} 
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Labeling a `\footnote` is trivial as one can simply call the `\label` command from within the footnote environment. However, LaTeX does not appear to support labeling of a `\footnotemark`. Please advise if there is an efficient solution to label a `\footnotemark`. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you're trying to do? Do you expect the label of the footnotemark to point to the footnotemark itself, or to the footnote? And should the `hyperref` link take you to the footnote, or to the footnotemark? Why do you want to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` instead of `\footnote{Footnote 1\label{fn:1}}`?

Comment: Hi @Jake: I merely want to store the value of the footnote counter at the point in time when the `\footnotemark` is placed. This way, I can place a series of footnotemarks, label each one with a number that corresponds to the footnote counter (e.g., `\arabic{footnote}`), and then subsequently print the corresponding `\footnotetext` with the appropriate number by referencing (`\ref`) the corresponding `\footnotemark`. The reason I wish to avoid the strategy you mentioned is that I intend to use footnotes within footnotes and the only way I know to achieve this is to place footnotemarks. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\footnotemark` executes `\stepcounter{footnote}` by default, which does not allow proper referencing. If you want to label a footnote, you need to use `\refstepcounter{footnote}`. As such, you would need to patch `\footnotemark` or do other trickery in order to obtain the correct result. `\footnotetext` on the other hand, has no counter associated with it and therefore cannot be referenced in the same way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
% Patch \footnotemark to provide a label that can be referenced.
\patchcmd{\footnotemark}{\stepcounter{footnote}}{\refstepcounter{footnote}}{}{}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
This text is footnoted\footnotemark\label{fnm:1} \footnotemark\label{fnm:2}
\footnotetext{Footnote `1'\label{fnt:1}.}%
\footnotetext{Footnote `2'\label{fnt:2}.}%

The numbers of the labels: %
\{\ref{fnm:1}, \ref{fnt:1}, \ref{fnm:2},  \ref{fnt:2}\}

The sequence should read: \{1, 1, 2, 2\} 
\end{document}
```

In order to adequately reference a `\footnotetext` with the same marker as some `\footnotemark`, you need to be able to pass an expandable reference of that marker to the specific `\footnotetext`'s optional argument. This is the technique that causes [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) incompatibility in [Nested footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38643/nested-footnotes).

Comment: Thank you @Werner. The patch you describe permits labeling of footnotemarks. As you have stated, if I subsequently attempt `\footnotetext[\ref{fnm:1}]{...}`, it appropriately numbers the footnotetext **if and only if** the `hyperref` package is omitted. You mention that this is due to the need to pass an expandable reference (perhaps `hyperref` chooses to act on the `\footnotetext` only if variable expansion is used?). I suppose there is no way "pre-expand" the reference and thereby pass in a literal? I notice there are no problems if a literal is passed.