# How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, footnotes, revtex

I am using REVTeX 4.1 with BibTeX for references.  The author guidelines for a journal state:

> Authors should ensure that the journal article contains a reference in
>   the reference list as follows:
>
> - See Supplemental Material at [URL will be inserted by publisher] for
>     [give brief description of material].

I used the `\footnote` command to achieve this, as it produces extra entries in the references section by default.

I would like to refer to the same Supplemental Material "reference" more than once.  How can I achieve this?

---

Minimal example.  In the real document I do have a `.bib` file too, not included here.

```
% proba.tex
\documentclass[footinbib]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
Some text here \footnote{Supplemental Material reference}. % produces ref. [1]

I would like to refer to the same Supplemental Material again here. % refer to [1] here somehow
\end{document}
```

Note that BibTeX *does* need to be run for this minimal example to work, according to the REVTeX documentation, despite no `.bib` file being present here.

```
pdflatex proba
bibtex proba
pdflatex proba
pdflatex proba
```

[image]

Perhaps the solution is not to use `\footnote` for this purpose.  What should I use in that case?

Comment: Additionally, would it be the same for TeXworks?

Comment: Look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38857/labeling-a-footnotemark

Comment: @giannis I'm not sure what you mean.  Isn't TeXworks just an IDE or editor?

Comment: @Szabolcs I've just meant if I could use the same code in TeXworks, which is an editor, I think. Already tried what suggested below and works perfectly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each `\footnote` under your document setup produces a bibliography key of the form `NoteX` where `X` is the regular footnote number. So, in your case, `\cite{Note1}` would reference the first footnote citation, while (say) `\cite{Note17}` would reference a citation in the footnotes corresponding to footnote number 17.

Here's a minimal example explaining its usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass[footinbib]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}
Some text here \footnote{Supplemental Material reference}, \setcounter{footnote}{16}\footnote{something else}.

I would like to refer to the same Supplemental Material again here \cite{Note1}, \cite{Note17}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

The option `footinbib` leads to the creation of an extra `.bib` file with entries of the form:

```
@MISC{NoteX,note="Supplemental Material reference"}
```

Instead of using footnotes, you can also add such entries to your `.bib` file and use standard cite commands.

Comment: Does it work ? I mean: will the editorial team accept this ?
Otherwise in REVTeX4-2, [@]FOOTNOTE is used instead of [@]MISC.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle I used it a few years ago with revtex4-1 and it was accepted.