# Directing to the same footnote multiple times in rextex4 (prl)

Tags: footnotes, revtex, footmisc

I wish to direct the reader to the same footnote multiple times (in different locations in the main text).

I have found solutions using `\footenote{\label{}...}` and, e.g., `\footref{}` or `\footnotemark[\ref{note1}]`. These solutions seem to fail when I use:

`\documentclass[prl,amsmath,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}`.

I also don't seem to make it work when I use (I tried recompiling with the packages from scratch):

`\usepackage{scrextend}`

or

`\usepackage{footmisc}`.

How can I do that in the document class which I'm using?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? This would help us to help you.

Comment: Does it have to be `revtex4` or is the more recent version `revtex4-1` acceptable?  For `revtex4-1` the problem is covered in [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/106162)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`revtex4-1`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) the answer is covered by [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/106162) Switching to [`revtex4-1`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) and using the answers from [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/106162) should probably be considered the preferred solution.

The (now obsolete) [`revtex4`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-0) uses a different mechanism, storing footnotes by default as endnotes which are sequentially labelled `endnoteX` where `X` is the number of the footnotes.  All these footnotes can be found in a `<tex file name>.end` auxiliary file which may be an easier way to find the appropriate endnote label.

The footnote can then be referenced a second time through use of the `\cite{endnoteX}` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass[prl,amsmath,onecolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}

\begin{document}
Foo~\footnote{bar}.  Let us reference that footnote again~\cite{endnote1}

\end{document}
```