# Merge (compress) references to citation and footnote in revtex4-1

Tags: citing, footnotes, revtex

There are many questions about REVTeX and footnotes or citations, but I cannot find the following. I'm writing an article using REVTeX and have a footnote following a citation. Since footnotes are processed as endnotes I would like to merge the references for the two to get something looking like

> Text [1,2].

where [1] refers to a citation and [2] to a footnote.
Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}

I would like \cite{key}\footnote{Footnote text} to look as \cite{key,hole}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{key} Author, \textit{Title}.
\bibitem{hole} Another author, \textit{Another title}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

(For me the footnote only compiles well in this example if I explicitly run bibtex.exe, but that's no problem in the full article. Maybe I should also point out that I really use `\bibliography{...}` and a .bib-file; I just want to make the above self contained and short.)

---

**Edit.** I noticed (cf [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187876/46852)) that it *is* possible to refer to the *K*th (in order of appearance) footnote by `\cite{NoteK}`. This seems to reduce my question to the following:

Is it possible to make a footnote that does appear as an endnote in the bibliography, but is not cited in the text? That is: is there a footnote-like analog of `\nocite` that works in this case?

Indeed, then we could just `\cite` it directly afterwards:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}

I would like \cite{key}\footnote{Footnote text} to look as \cite{key,Note1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{key} Author, \textit{Title}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding your last edit: What's the point of having an endnote which is not referenced in the main text? How is the reader supposed to know what the note is referring to?

Comment: @campa fair enough; I have updated the edit to explain what I have in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `\footnotetext`?  You can even give a number as optional argument.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}

\footnotetext[5]{My possibly unused footnote text}

\cite{key,Note5}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{key} Author, \textit{Title}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]