# Merge references to bibliography item and footnote in achemso, using bibnote

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, achemso

My question is the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354745/merge-compress-references-to-citation-and-footnote-in-revtex4-1): basically I would like to put footnotes in the bibliography and I would like them to be treated exactly as any other bibliography item.

However I have different constraints, so the accepted answer of the linked question does not solve my problem.

I have to use the `achemso` style, and for the footnotes I have to use `bibnote` (not `footnotetext`). Also, for the bibliography I must use `bibtex`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{bib1,
author = {Guy, A.},
journal = {American Journal of Journals},
number = {42},
pages = {42},
title = {Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything},
volume = {42},
year = {1942}
}
@article{bib2,
title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
journal={Physical review},
volume={47},
year={1935},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[journal=mamobx,manuscript=article,layout=traditional]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
I would like \cite{bib1}\bibnote{Footnote text} to look as \cite{bib1,bib2}.
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

And here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: If you want to cite your note in the same citation as other refs, you _have_ to make the reference 'by hand' and add it 'traditionally' ...

Comment: @JosephWright I understand. In this case, what bibtex entry type do you suggest to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where you want to have a single `\cite` with a 'real' citation and a note, there is little option but to create the note entry 'by hand'

```
@misc{Note1,
  howpublished = {Some interesting note}
}

...

\cite{bib1,Note1}
```