# grouping footnotes and citations in superscript formatting

Tags: bibliographies, citing

When using superscript formatting for citations, the citations are grouped in the superscript with either a comma (if there are two) or an en-dash (if there are more than two). However, if I have a footnote and a citation that are sequential, then there is no comma in the superscript, just the two numbers side-by-side.

example.tex:

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

Text\cite{Ref1,Ref2}

Text\footnote{Blah}\cite{Ref1}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

and test.bib:

```
@article{Ref1,
title = {Tit1},
author = {Aut1}
}

@article{Ref2,
title = {Tit2},
author = {Aut2}
}
```

Produce

[image]

Is there a way to group together mixed footnote and citation references like the two citations?

Comment: There are packages that allows multiple footnotes, and some of them have some support with citations. But there are quite a few different citation styles/packages. Please edit your question with a minimum example that shows whether you are using bibtex or biblatex, and whether you are using something like apacite or natbib.

Comment: Added an example. revtex uses bibtex and natbib, I believe.

Comment: For revtex note [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/106162) and try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410906/106162)

Comment: Thanks @DaiBowen, I tried that solution as well, but found that I would have to specify some arbitrarily high note number just so that it didn't conflict with the other notes. So, I think I like the solution that Willie Wong proposed slightly better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution using `fnpct`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511158/119) also works here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\AdaptNote\cite{oom}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {#NOTE{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#NOTE[#1]{#3}}{#NOTE[#1][#2]{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Text\cite{Ref1,Ref2}

Text\footnote{Blah}\cite{Ref1}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```